# Is there set division in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra, set-theory

I'm fully aware that set division can be accomplished through a series of other operations, so my question is:

Is there a command for set division in SQL?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by set division? Do you mean things like intersection?

Comment: Also, are you talking about ANSI SQL, or a particular vendor's implementation of SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://vadimtropashko.files.wordpress.com/2007/02/ch3.pdf

From Page 32:

> Relational Division is not a fundamental operator. It can be expressed in terms of projection, Cartesian product, and set difference.

So, no. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a nice explanation using relational algebra syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29).

Given tables `sailors`, `boats` and `reserves` (examples from Ramakrishnan & Gehrke's "Database Management Systems") you can compute sailors who have reserved all boats with the following query:

```
SELECT name FROM sailors
WHERE Sid NOT IN (
    -- A sailor is disqualified if by attaching a boat,
    -- we obtain a tuple <sailor, boat> that is not in reserves
    SELECT s.Sid
    FROM sailors s, boats b
    WHERE (s.Sid, b.Bid) NOT IN (
        SELECT Sid, Bid FROM reserves
    )
);

-- Alternatively:
SELECT name FROM sailors s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- Not reserved boats
    (SELECT bid FROM boats)
    EXCEPT
    (SELECT r.bid FROM reserves r
    WHERE r.sid = s.sid)
);
```

Comment: I audited Gehrke's Intro class and I can confirm all the examples were nautical :)

Answer (score 2):

Related question: [Database Design for Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475/database-design-for-tagging)

And relevant part of answer is [this article](http://www.dbazine.com/ofinterest/oi-articles/celko1)

So in short, no, there is no set division in SQL.