# How to query items with identical set of values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm looking for an efficient way to query items, that have identical set of values.

I have a following table

```
C_1  C_2
--------
A    1
A    2
-------
B    1
B    2
B    3
-------
C    1
C    2
-------
D    1
D    2
D    3
-------
E    1
E    2 
-------
F    0
F    2
```

I will select the list of items FROM C_1 that have exact the same set of c_2 elements as the given item.

For item A i will have

```
C
E
```

For item B i will have

```
D
```

how can it be done in SQL( Oracle 10g )?

---

Here is the create table statement for test purposes

```
create table t (c_1 varchar2(1), c_2 number);
INSERT into t VALUES('A',    1);
INSERT into t VALUES('A',    2);
INSERT into t VALUES('B',    1);
INSERT into t VALUES('B',    2);
INSERT into t VALUES('B',    3);
INSERT into t VALUES('C',    1);
INSERT into t VALUES('C',    2);
INSERT into t VALUES('D',    1);
INSERT into t VALUES('D',    2);
INSERT into t VALUES('D',    3);
INSERT into t VALUES('E',    1);
INSERT into t VALUES('E',    2); 
INSERT into t VALUES('F',    0);
INSERT into t VALUES('F',    2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 10g's [`COLLECT`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions024.htm#i1271564) function; since you don't want to see what the c_2 values are you don't even need to `cast` it.

```
select c_1
from t
where c_1 != 'A'
group by c_1
having collect(c_2) = (select collect(c_2) from t where c_1 = 'A' group by c_1)
/
```

Comment: I'm no expert on Oracle, so thanks for introducing me to COLLECT and nested tables :)  I would upvote, but Marcink's answer is more generic...

Comment: That's a very nice idea. Sometimes those yet relational extensions really are neat.

Answer (score 3):

```
create type t_c_2 as table of number;

select one.c_1, two.c_1
from (select t.c_1, CAST(COLLECT(t.c_2) as t_c_2) coll
      from t
      group by t.c_1) one
    ,(select t.c_1, CAST(COLLECT(t.c_2) as t_c_2) coll
      from t
      group by t.c_1) two
where one.coll = two.coll
  and one.c_1 != two.c_1;
```

I've never used such a construction on a production site, efficiency verification is needed.

Answer (score 2):

What you need can be achieved with a division:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29

Or a similar question:

[Is there set division in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110088/is-there-set-division-in-sql)

Unfortunately, divisions aren't as easy to express with SQL as with relational algebra.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  [search].c_1,
  [match].c_1
FROM
  t      AS [search]
INNER JOIN
  t      AS [match]
    ON [search].c_2 = [match].c_2
GROUP BY
  [search].c_1,
  [match].c_1
HAVING
      COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE c_1 = [search].c_1)
  AND COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE c_1 = [match].c_1)
```

For maximum performance, you need two indexes.  One on `c_1` and another on `c_2`.
- The index on `c_1` makes the two `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries simple index lookups.
- The index on `c_2` makes the join a lookup.

You could add `AND [search].c_1 != [match].c_1` to stop a set matching itself.

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_1
  FROM (SELECT c_1, c_2, COUNT(*) over(PARTITION BY c_1) cnt FROM t)
 WHERE (SELECT MAX(c_2) FROM t WHERE c_1 = 'A') = cnt
   AND c_1 <> 'A'
```

Not sure about the performance, you could try to otpimize it a little, tell me if it works

Comment: I think that only works if the `c_2` values are contiguous and all start from one. If you knock out, say, `D,2` then `D` is included in the results for `A`, because the highest value for `A` matches the number of values for `D` - not the exact same set of values.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it worked only if the values in c_2 are sequential. I don't know anything about the distribution of values in C_2. I have added the rows for the "F" item in my question. You query will return "F" as well. But "F" doesn't have exact the same set of c_2 values as "A"