# How to write a query to join 2 tables and only return records where MULTIPLE child records are included in a set of possibilities

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, join, left-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

I am working on a SQL statement for my android app that has a special JOIN requirement. There are 2 tables, one for a PERSON and one for INTEREST. A PERSON may have multiple INTERESTS.

I'm looking for a query that will return only the people that have **ALL** of the specified interests. Here are my sample tables:

```
PERSON
_id | name
1   | Bob
2   | Harry
3   | Lucy
4   | Sally

INTERESTS
_id | person | interest
1   | bob    | skiing
2   | bob    | biking
3   | bob    | swimming
4   | harry  | skiing
5   | harry  | surfing
6   | harry  | swimming
```

I want the query to find all people that like BOTH skiing and biking (ie only bob). I would also lie it to return a record for bob only once, if at all possible. Can SQLite do such a query? If so, how?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is called Set Division. See example with boats and sailors here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110088/is-there-set-division-in-sql

Comment: And this one: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Comment: Thanks Bulat. Looks like you were right. I choose a different solution since this one was not available. I appreciate your link and the education it provided me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the other solutions, using the `Exists()` operator is an easy way of doing this type of request, something like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM person p Where Exists (Select * from interests i where i.person = p.name and i.interest = 'skiing') and Exists (Select * from interests i where i.person = p.name and i.interest = 'biking')
```

Also, you should store the `_id` of the table `person` as a foreign key in your table `interests` instead of the `name`.  This way, you can have multiple persons with the same name or later change the name of a person without having to change the values in your other related tables.

It's also not a good idea to use the plural form for the name of the table `interests` but the singular form for the name of the table `person`.

Comment: Thanks SylvainL. Fr my purposes the names are actually the unique identifiers (they are for products, not people). I just used people as an example. I hope that was not misleading.I ended up cheating this a bit by de-normalizing the data. I created a lookup table that has the name and then used the GROUP_CONCAT(interest.interest) for each name and it works like a charm. Possiblly not something I would to for 10 million rows, but for 2K rows it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I generally JOIN the table multiple times, but this can be tricky if you don't know the search criteria.  Meaning, if you are searching by 2 different interests, you'd join the interest table twice.

Something like this will work for your question above:

```
select distinct p.name
from person p
    join interests i on p.name = i.person and i.interest = 'skiing'
    join interests i2 on p.name = i2.person and i2.interest = 'biking'
```

This should return you Bob.

As a side note, you should store the personid in your interests table rather than the name.  And consider introducing a PersonInterests table with PersonId and InterestId - that would be even better for normalization.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one:

SELECT p.name FROM person p JOIN interests i on p.name = i.person
              GROUP BY p.name HAVING count(*) = 2
              WHERE i.interest in ('skiing', 'biking').

And I agree it'd be better use person id in interests table instead of name. Another suggestion: you should have separate table with interest id and have only two ids in table person interests.