# GUID vs Identity for use with tags

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, tags

I know this subject has been discussed at length (I have read lots of posts here and all over the web) and I don't like to flog a dead horse but I have a question about a more specific aspect of Integer ID vs GUID:

I am writing out a schema which is going to have a tagging ability similar in use to the stackoverflow tags but it will have the same tags used against 5+ different tables.

The basic tables I will be linking are as follows:

**Tag Table**

```
Tag ID    Tag Name      Tag Description
-------------------------------------------------------------
     1    Hats          Tag for hats
     2    Coats         Tag for coats
     3    Gloves        Gloves tag
     4    Ladies        Ladies item
```

**Items Table 1**

```
Item ID    Item Name    Cost
------------------------------------------------------------
      1    Deerstalker  £20.00
      2    Fedora       £50.00
      3    Scarf        £15.00
```

The bit I'm having trouble with is the `tag_item` table.

I will have 5 tables with completely different structures that I want the users to be able to apply tags to so I think I'll need to do one of the following:

- Store `table name`/`table number` as well as the integer key of the row the tag relates to
- Store a `GUID` of the row, this will work independent of the table and make it much easier to get all tags for a certain row.

What I'm unsure of is how this will affect performance for:

- Searching for all items over 5 tables with a certain tag/tags
- editing the tags for an item
- joins

Is there any clearly better option in this case or anywhere I could read up on the advantages in this particular scenario?

---

**Edit:**

For anyone interested, below is the schema I have decided upon:

Table for Tags

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sys_TagList](

    [Sys_Tag_Primary] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sys_Tag_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Sys_Tag_Description] [varchar](1000) NULL

)
```

Table for Tag_Items

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Meta_Tags](

    [Met_Tag_Primary] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Met_Tag_Link_FK] [int] NOT NULL, -- Link to [Sys_Tag_Primary] field
    [Met_Tag_Name] [varchar](25) NOT NULL, -- To enable tag searches to use a single table
    [Met_Tag_Table] [varchar](25) NOT NULL, -- Table name, used with [Met_Tag_RowID] to create link to that item
    [Met_Tag_RowID] [int] NOT NULL -- Primary key of item[n] table

)
```

Comment: "*Store a GUID of the row, this will ... make it much easier to get all tags for a certain row.*"  No, it really will not.  Just store two columns, the TableName (or a TypeID that identifies the table) and the RowID.  GUIDs will not help with this problem the way that you think they will, they are just going to make things more difficult, complex and confusing.  Virtually everyone does it this way (a table identifier and a row identifier).

Comment: @RBarryYoung, can you explain your reasons as to why `GUID` is not a valid solution?

Comment: It's perfectly valid, it just not easier and likely to be harder.  It boils down to two things: 1) GUID are an unusual datatype that is slightly clumsier to handle on both the client and server than the usual key types (integers and strings), and 2) having to search all possible tables to figure out which one a GUID belongs to is not only slower, it is a gigantic Pain-In-The-Ankle code-wise.  The is especially true for SQL queries/code, because it ***so*** much wants to know it's column set ahead of time.

Comment: (cont.) If you actually try it (I have) you will quickly realize that "Key then Table" is exactly the wrong order for how you want to work in SQL.  You will always want to know the Table first.

Comment: Will all tags always be applicable to all tables?  E.g. "Chrome" may apply to men's heads, but not houseplants.  You may want to consider adding either a mask to indicate the applicabilty of each tag or making separate tag tables.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to (perhaps unhelpfully) suggest that GUID vs ID is the wrong question to be focusing on. The assumption that you need a single table linking tags to items may be worth examining first.

If your five item categories are different enough to require different tables then you should probably consider five tag_item link tables - one for each item table. Although the code to query them all at once (using `UNION ALL` to concatenate the results) may be a bit more verbose and repetetive than the code for a single link table, the queries are likely to be substantially simpler - good from both a maintenance and a query-plan perspective.

The other alternative would be to refactor the common attributes that the five item categories share into a single central table (to which the tags are linked) and store the additional non-common attributes in five child tables. It's difficult to know whether this is appropriate without some more information about how the existing data is currently used.

Comment: I do like this idea although it seems complex when listing tag entries and the different tables they relate to, unless in the query doing something like `SELECT 'TableName' as Source...` in each `UNION`?

Comment: @bendataclear - yes, that (or some other type indicator) would work

Comment: isn't that just the same as storing `Table name` and `Table Primary Key` as two columns in the tag_item linking table?

Comment: @bendataclear - no, because the "type" data isn't materialised, there's no need to add indexes to support it

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory possible [tagging design duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475/database-design-for-tagging)

Depending on how you intend to use the tags and what performance characteristics are important, one possible alternative to the map/link table is a hashed combination table.

Calculate the hash of a given requested combination of tags and store that directly in your existing tables, and in the combination table.

Querying for anything that is a subset of tags might start to get kind of hacky though as you'll end up doing a lot of in memory transforms of all those hashes.  Perhaps there is a cleaner way of querying hashed reference values out there, as I cant recall doing this, and didn't immediately locate anything in a search.