# what is the best approach to store keywords inside database, language agnostic

Tags: c#, java, .net, database-design, language-agnostic

My question title is self explanatory.

I'm aware that there is no exact answer on this subject cause it depends on many subjects but if you have time to share ideas and thought on how would you collect keywords, store them into db. Pseudo code would be just fine, or plain english.

Here's what I'm thinking

**Collecting keywords from the user**

User enters using some form (web or desktop) and sends them to the database.

```
txtKeyword1 = "one"; txtKeyword2 = "two"; txtKeyword3= "three";
```

**How keyword is represent inside database**

With TEXT field containing `"one two three"`

**Problem**
With using this approach I'm coming to the problem when I want to display keywords separated one from another. I was thinking to separate each word with ','(comma) but what if keyword has more than one word?

Should I use one more property inside viewmodel to represent separated keywords as `List<string>Keywords` property (once I come with solution how to separate them) or I should store this property directly inside domain object.

Please share you're thoughts.

Thank you

Please ask if you need more information.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to store keywords inside database

Comment: A table with a `varchar` column?.. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Even following a process of normalization for the logical design and denormalization for the physical design - multiple values within a database field should be avoided: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Self explanatory?  Why don't you tell us all of the required information?  How many keywords you will have per entry, for example, is *really* important.  Will it always be three?  Will it be up to three?  Will it be a hundred, a thousand - no limit?

Comment: no, it will not always be three, no limit.

Comment: @J you suggest that I use one TEXT db field with separating every value by comma for example one, two, three, four and five, six, ... s that right?

Comment: @J ok, pleast post as an answer.

Comment: i think you are looking for tag solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475/database-design-for-tagging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a one-to-many relationship of records and keywords.  Best achieved by using three tables:

The first table should have the records, and no reference to the keywords.

The second table should be just single individual keywords.

The final table is a lookup table.  For each keyword that a record has, this table has an entry for the index of the keyword and an index of the keyword.

Comment: This is the best solution, especially if cross-referencing is going to be important.

Comment: so when seeing this from ddd perspective keyword would be an component cause I don't need to track keywords by it's identity, right?

Comment: ddd perspective keyword ? What are you trying to say?

Comment: If I understand the proposed solution correctly in DDD speak: the records and keywords tables would be entities whilst the lookup table would be an aggregate.