# Find matching items by complex combination of attributes

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

In my database, I have items, which reflect attributes on documents being filled out by users. Each value given in a document, e.g. you select a certain option for a field or select a check-box, becomes an item/attribute in my table.

Such attributes could be: Smoker, Non-Smoker, Region (Europe, USA, ...), Hair-Color

In the tables, this roughly looks like the following:

```
Document
ID | Name
1  | doc-1
2  | doc-2
3  | doc-3

Attribute
ID | Name
1  | Smoker
2  | Non-Smoker
3  | Region-Europe
4  | Region-USA
5  | Hair-Brown
6  | Hair-Blond

Item
ID | Document | Attribute
1  | 1        | 1
2  | 1        | 4
3  | 2        | 2
4  | 2        | 3
5  | 2        | 5
6  | 3        | 2
7  | 3        | 6
```

To offer search possibilities, it shall be possible to allow the users for building generic queries. For example, I would like to find the documents, which have the following attributes:

```
(Smoker AND Region-USA) OR (Non-Smoker AND Region-Europe AND Hair-Blond)
```

(would result in document #1 being found)

How can I execute such a query in the most efficient way, and maybe use EF-core and linq-to-sql to push that down to SQL?
How could I actually query for that in plan SQL the most efficient way?

I can do it quite easy in memory, but since my database contains 100k+ items, this might get slow pretty soon.

Thank you for any help on this!

---

**Update**: Related questions on SO

- [Database Design for Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475/database-design-for-tagging)

Comment: I would say go ahead and use whatever method you have that works in memory and see if it is actually too slow in practice. You might find that it works just fine. "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." ~Donald Knuth

Comment: Do you want to know how to answer the specific query listed, or do you need to handle general queries at runtime?

Comment: @NetMage: I will rephrase the question a little bit. I should be able to handle general queries, as the user can build a query using a UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More research showed me, what I already expected: the solution using the SQL IN statement could be used and is actually working to nicely dispatch that query work to the server, but may not be that efficient on a large number of tags.

Luckily, users won't execute very complex queries on a regular basis and would accept a little waiting time on complex queries, so I can neglect that in my case.

To link the sources for these statements:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480/8504288
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176816

To roughly sketch the final solution now, here is some code for that:

By using the IN statement, in the sub-query, I can filter all documents, which have a certain attribute applied. By combining those IN statements using AND/OR, I can build my desired expression.

```sql
SELECT i.Document
FROM   Item i INNER JOIN Attribute a on i.Attribute = a.ID
WHERE
    i.Document IN (
       SELECT ii.Document 
       FROM Item ii INNER JOIN Attribute ai on ii.Attribute = ai.ID
       WHERE ai.Name = "Smoker"
    )
    AND
    i.Document IN (
       SELECT ii.Document 
       FROM Item ii INNER JOIN Attribute ai on ii.Attribute = ai.ID
       WHERE ai.Name = "Region-USA"
    )
    OR
    i.Document IN (
       SELECT ii.Document 
       FROM Item ii INNER JOIN Attribute ai on ii.Attribute = ai.ID
       WHERE ai.Name = "Non-Smoker"
    )
    AND
    i.Document IN (
       SELECT ii.Document 
       FROM Item ii INNER JOIN Attribute ai on ii.Attribute = ai.ID
       WHERE ai.Name = "Region-Europe"
    )
    AND
    i.Document IN (
       SELECT ii.Document 
       FROM Item ii INNER JOIN Attribute ai on ii.Attribute = ai.ID
       WHERE ai.Name = "Hair-Blond"
    )
```

**Performance improvement**

To maybe limit the amount of JOINs needed in the sub-queries, one could select the IDs of the attributes needed first.

```sql
SELECT ID, Name FROM Attribute WHERE Name in ('Smoker', 'Non-Smoker', ...)
```

Using these IDs, the sub-query would look much easier, as we would be able to skip the JOIN:

```sql
SELECT i.Document
FROM   Item i INNER JOIN Attribute a on i.Attribute = a.ID
WHERE
    i.Document IN (SELECT ii.Document FROM Item ii WHERE ii.Attribute = 1) -- Smoker
    AND
    i.Document IN (SELECT ii.Document FROM Item ii WHERE ii.Attribute = 4) -- Region-USA
    OR
    ...
```

---

*Update*

**Measured times for both approaches**

I did execute a similar query as the mentioned query above: (1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4 AND 4) on SQL Server, with a reasonably sized set of Documents (130), Items (4122) and Attributes (~400).
The following times could be measured on my machine:

- 1st approach, with JOIN in sub-query of IN: ~ 12 secs
- 2nd approach, with ID lookup of attribute first: ~3.5 secs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LINQ extension class to help with building queries. I leave parsing the expression and building the correct query as an exercise for the reader :).

First, here is the basis for what we will build:

```
public class DocItemJoin {
    public Documents d { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> ig { get; set; }
}

var DocItems = Document.GroupJoin(Item, d => d.ID, i => i.Document, (d, ig) => new DocItemJoin { d = d, ig = ig.Select(i => i.Attribute) });

// (Smoker AND Region-USA) OR (Non-Smoker AND Region-Europe AND Hair-Blond)    
var ans = DocItems.Where(dig => (dig.ig.Contains(1) && dig.ig.Contains(4)) || (dig.ig.Contains(2) && dig.ig.Contains(3) && dig.ig.Contains(6)))
                  .Select(dig => dig.d);
```

Using `DocItems` as the base, we can query for each attribute using `Contains`.

Using the extension library, we can build the same query dynamically:

```
var whereLeft = 1.HasAttrib().qAnd(4.HasAttrib());
var whereRight = 2.HasAttrib().qAnd(3.HasAttrib()).qAnd(6.HasAttrib());
var whereBody = whereLeft.qOr(whereRight);
var ans = DocItems.Query(whereBody);
```

Finally, here is the extension class the builds the `Expression` trees:

```
public static class QueryBuilder {
    private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(mi => mi.Name == "Contains" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

    public static MethodCallExpression qContains(this Expression p, int attrib) => Expression.Call(containsMethod, p, Expression.Constant(attrib));
    public static BinaryExpression qAnd(this Expression l, Expression r) => Expression.AndAlso(l, r);
    public static BinaryExpression qOr(this Expression l, Expression r) => Expression.OrElse(l, r);

    static ParameterExpression digParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DocItemJoin), "dig");
    static MemberExpression digParmig = Expression.Property(digParm, "ig");

    public static MethodCallExpression HasAttrib(this int attrib) => digParmig.qContains(attrib);

    static Expression<Func<DocItemJoin, Documents>> selectLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<DocItemJoin, Documents>>(Expression.Property(digParm, "d"), digParm);

    public static IQueryable<Documents> Query(this IQueryable<DocItemJoin> src, Expression whereBody)
        => src.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<DocItemJoin, bool>>(whereBody, digParm)).Select(selectLambda);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the provided solution. I like the extensions for the expressions. However, I doubt that I can push that down to the level of SQL

Comment: @HaraldKöstinger I tested the manual expression with LINQ to SQL, and it translated to SQL expressions fine?