# GridView and ObjectDataSource issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

Here's the problem I'm having in my asp project.

My shopping cart consists of 3 classes like the picture below.

The class **Carrinho** has a List of **Arranjo** wich by itself has a List of **Product**.

Now I want to display the **Carrinho's**  list and I have a GridView whose data source is an ObjectDataSource that's associated to the **Carrinho** object. It should display, for now, just the **Total** property from **Arranjo** but I keep getting an empty page always.
I have debugged the project and the list is definitely not empty.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: classes picture]

Comment: Your GridView is bind to a Carrinho Object or a list of Carrinho ? because you have not a method that return a Carrinho Object

Comment: My ObjectDataSource is bind to Carrinho and the SELECT method is SelectAll() wich returns the list of Arranjo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not regular to do that (biding a list of list<*object*>  ) .
Any way if you insist to do that you should know you need to bind a list of object to each item in GridView Row , So that item should be like List controls .
otherwise you should convert your field to "**ItemTemplate**" and you bind by your own .
[Here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276126/best-way-to-databind-a-list-with-sub-related-content-for-example-sos-questions#276240)

Hope that helps

Comment: Just to clarify a little bit more...it's a web Flower Shop.
A client can choose various bouquets and each bouquet has many flowers. That's why I have a list of list. Each cart has X bouquets with Y flowers.

Comment: You can Convert you column in GridView into ItemTemplate and put some ListControls like BulletList then you should bind them by you own