# What are good APIs or search method for tagging objects into categories and searching them?

Tags: search, web, tagging

i want to tag many user created content and have multiple types of categories (project tags, desc tag, style/inspiration tag etc). I seen horrible search engines where the more words you use the worse your result is and i dont want that with tagging.

What are good APIs or search method for tagging objects into categories and searching them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check these questions out:

- [How do you recommend implementing tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging)
- [What is the most efficient way to store tags in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334183/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database)

They both describe the same approach which should be easily tweakable to allow you to organize your tags into different categories.