# Best approach to storing tags in database

Tags: php, javascript, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practice for storing tags in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508207/best-practice-for-storing-tags-in-a-database)

Hi there,

I'm looking into the best approach to keeping information in a database.
If I had a 'blog' or any other website that had tags. What is the best way to keep these tags?

With Wordpress I know they keep the tags in a separate table and have a FR key back to the post.

Would storing the tags in a JSON format in the posts table be a better approach? And how would that work with searching for tags?

I understand that it depends on my needs, but any ideas on the best way to store and search for tags would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The tags should be in a separate table, exactly for the purpose of searching, counting, owner information etc. If you've had the tags in the posts table you'd generate duplicate data which in this case is easy to avoid using a separate table.