# Aggregating many user created items into one "general" item

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, database-design

I'm building a site where users can inventory items and apply various attributes to it, eg. photos, urls, comments, etc.

I have a database structure of three tables:
`users`, `entries`, `associations`.

The tables have the following fields:

**users**
`id | joined | email | salt | password`

**entries**
`id | created | creator | type | value`

**associations**
`id | created | creator | type | node1 | node2`

Here's a breakdown of the site function:

**Users adding items to their inventory**
All user-created items go in `entries` with a `type` of 'item'. A row is added to `associations` with `type` 'possession', `node1` *users.id* and `node2` *entries.id*. This associations row is how I would (using INNER JOIN entries) pull and display a user's inventory (not just pulling all entries where creator = users.id, because a user may create an item they don't own).

**Adding attributes to items**
This part is what seems to throw off everyone I explain things to. An "attribute" is really just another item. In this way, it basically renders a user-created free-form hierarchy. E.g., You may 'tag' *For Whom The Bell Tolls* with "Book", and Book is another item (whether or not it's in the user's inventory matters not). To makes this work, I just add another row to the `associations` table with `type` 'tag' and node1 *entries.id* (parent item) and node2 *entries.id* ('tag' or child item). Remember than an entry may also be a url, comment, photo, etc, it would just depend on `entries.type`. Now I can pull all an items attributes. Eg, all photos: ($item_id = page I'm looking at) `"SELECT * FROM entries INNER JOIN associations ON associations.node1 = $item_id AND associations.node2 = entries.id AND entries.type = 'photo'`.

I can use a similar query to pull all an item's comments, it's url, whatever. This allows me to create a fluid system of associations between items, items and their owners, items and comments, comments and comments (replies).

My question is, once I have many user created entries of an item eg., "MacBook", what would be the best way to merge, aggregate, amalgamate or however else you like to call it, all those individual items into one general item, so that all these pieces of data created by users can be one knowledge chunk, if you will.

Again, I'm not so worried about users entering "mac book" "Apple Macbook" etc. En masse, those users are just doing it wrong and won't effect the community.

Basically, if a user that didn't own "MacBook" did a search and landed on the MacBook page, they would see the most popular tags, some photos (random, popular, whatever, that's trivial), comments about it, most popular URL, etc.

Also, thanks so much for taking time to read my confusing and elaborate description! :)

Comment: How do you determine which "items" fall into one of your "general item" pages?

Comment: `name` I suppose. If I want a general MacBook page, I would be trying to aggregate all pages where `name` = 'MacBook'.

Comment: Who defines the allowable names?  Also, you should be thinking about how specific the names are.. Would a particular type/version of Mac Book have its own page?

Comment: 1. There is no list of allowable names. If you want to add Jackalope to your inventory, then it ends up there. If another user does the same, then those two items would aggregately form the Jackalope page.
2. As for specificity, this is also sort of up to the user, however, the 'proper' way to do it would be to use the familiar name of the item, eg. just MacBook or MacBook Pro, and then tag it with 13", Snow Leopard, etc. I realize that not all user entered items will conform to one another in punctuation, capitalization, etc, but I've included a jQuery autocomplete to help curtail this.

Comment: K.  Check out my proposed answer

Answer (score 1):

Have a table called "Tags", which would have a unique Name field.  Whenever a user enters a new Name, it's added there.

Every Item should be linked to that table.  This sounds like a many items to one tag arrangement, so you wouldn't need an Item_Tags table, just a foreign key Tag_Id in the Items table.

For Comments, you just have a Comments table which links to that table.

To display only 4 photos, you do a SELECT of photos that are joined to that name (presumably, they're photos of Items that have that Name) and LIMIT 4

For other/similar design patterns, do a search for questions related to tags, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334183/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database).

Comment: Okay, that's helpful. But I still wonder how I'm going to determine popular tags, etc. It seems like it would be very resource intensive to query the associations for all items associated with the page, and then in each one of those items gather all the tags associated with the item and then determine which are most popular.

Comment: Determining popular tags-- SELECT the COUNT of Items/Comments/Whatever linked to that tag.  Querying a sample of Items and their tags/properties for a given page is not very resource intensive. As for your "associations" system, you didn't describe that very well in your question.  I'm not sure that an "Associations" table is even necessary

Comment: You might want have a 'clean' and 'dirty' version of your tags where you do some parsing to try and unify what they enter. e.g you might turn it all into lowercase & remove punctuation to try and 'clean' something like "MacBook" and "macbook" and end up with something consistnet.

Comment: Sorry for the poor description. Tried to pare down my question, and probably made it more obscure. I'll edit my question.