# Tagging query with group_concat

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Using the database schema for tagging from this question's accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334183/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database) is it possible to have a query using group_concat that works with a large amount of data? I need to get items with their tags for all items tagged with tag x. Using a query with group_concat having ~ .5 million tags is very slow at > 15 seconds. Without group_concat (items **without** tags) it is ~ 0.05 seconds.

As a side question, how does SO solve this problem?

Comment: can you give sample records.

Comment: SO seems to solve this problem by limiting questions to at most 5 tags. And what makes you think it uses `GROUP_CONCAT()` at all when dealing with tags?

Comment: @Barmar: the tag limit on SO is not for performance reasons, but rather [to keep questions focused](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34743); as for [SO's schema](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678), tags are associated with posts in both a normalised fashion (the `PostTags` table) and also a denormalised fashion (the `Posts.Tags` field) - the latter makes it very quick to retrieve a post's tags with the post itself, whereas the former makes it easy to search for posts with particular tag combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a case of a poor indexing strategy.  Adapting the schema shown in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/334246) of the question to which you linked:

```
CREATE Table Items (
  Item_ID    SERIAL,
  Item_Title VARCHAR(255),
  Content    TEXT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Tags (
  Tag_ID     SERIAL,
  Tag_Title  VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Items_Tags (
  Item_ID    BIGINT UNSIGNED REFERENCES Items (Item_ID),
  Tag_ID     BIGINT UNSIGNED REFERENCES Tags  ( Tag_ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (Item_ID, Tag_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Note that:

- MySQL's `SERIAL` data type is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE` and, as such, is indexed;
- defining the foreign key constraints in `Items_Tags` creates indexes on the foreign key columns.

Comment: Hmm I'm fairly sure I do have the same indexes, will check later tonight.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to have a hybrid between [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) data and [denormalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) data .
So using the normalized structure provided by *eggyal* i would do the following denormalized structure :

```
CREATE TABLE Items_Tags_Denormalized (
  Item_ID    BIGINT UNSIGNED REFERENCES Items (Item_ID),
  Tags     BLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY (Item_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In column `Tags` you would have all the tags (`Tag_Title`) for the corresponding `Item_ID`.
Now you have 2 ways to achieve this:

- create a cron that runs periodically which will build this table `Items_Tags_Denormalized` using `GROUP_CONCAT` or whatever suits you (advantage: doesn't put additional load when you insert or delete in `Items_Tags` table; disadvantage:  the denormalized table will not always be up to date (depending on how often do you run the cron))
- create [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for `Items_Tags` table on insert and delete in order to keep up to date the `Items_Tags_Denormalized` table (advantage: the denormalized table will always be up to date;disadvantage: additional load when you insert or delete in `Items_Tags` table)

Choose whatever solution suits your needs best considering the advantages and disadvantages.

So in the end you will have the `Items_Tags_Denormalized` table from which you will **only read without doing additional operations**.

Comment: Why not add the denormalised `Tags` field to the `Items` table (which is how SO does it)?

Comment: it is crucial to have separate models : one normalized and one denormalized , your solution is ok but from design pov i would suggest  to keep it separate for various reasons : you need to rebuild the table , you need to add more columns etc plus if you add denormalized tags column in items the performance of the table will drop  : bigger size = slower queries

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use group_concat for that? For a given tag x you said that selecting the list of items is  fast. For a given list of items getting all the tags should be fast, too. And is there not normally some kind of restriction, I mean normal websites don't show 100000 entries on one page.

I would suggest:

```
drop temporary table if exists lookup_item;

create temporary table lookup_item (item_id serial, primary key(item_id));

insert into lookup_item select i.id as item_id 
from items i 
where exists (select * from items_tags where item_id = i.id and tag_id = <tag_id>)
and <other conditions or limits>;

select * from lookup_item
inner join items_tags it on it.item_id = i.id
inner join tags t on t.id = it.tag_id
order by i.<priority>, t.<priority>
```

priority could be last-modified for items and some kind of importance for tags.

Then you get every item with it's tags. The only work in the code is to see when the result-line has the next item.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `GROUP_CONCAT` isn't the only thing you are removing that makes the query faster without tags. Inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` you're selecting `Tags.Tag_Title` and forcing the Tags table to be accessed.

You could try running `GROUP_CONCAT` with `Items_Tags.Tag_ID` to test my theory.