# good way to store tags in relational database when there are variable numbers of tags associated with each piece of information

Tags: sql, database, tags, relational, varying

I want to store sentences that can be tagged with variable numbers of tags in an SQL relational database. So, I may have a sentence such as

```
'As the sun sets slowly in the west, we bid you a fine farewell.'
```

tagged with the following tags:

```
'farewell', 'goodbye', 'amiable'
```

The number of tags for a sentence can vary. In the example given here, there are three tags.

What would be a sensible way to organise this type of information in a relational database? What tables etc. would be reasonable?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to store tags in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334183/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship. Make three tables: `sentence`, `tag` and `sentence_tag`. The `sentence` and `tag` tables will each have a primary key `id` field and `sentence_tag` will have a `sentence_id` field and a `tag_id` field. To find the tags for a sentence with `id = $sID`,

```
SELECT tag_name FROM tags WHERE id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM sentence_tag WHERE sentence_id = $sID);
```