# What is the most efficient way to create models for storing tags in Django 1.9 and Postgres 9.5?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I want to make a model where I have the option of pulling a group of items and their descriptions from a postgres database based on tags. What is the most efficient way of doing this for performance using Django 1.9 and Postgres 9.5 on data that I do not really modify often?

I found multiple ways of doing this:

**Toxi solution** 
Where 3 tables are made, one storing the item and descriptions, second storing the tags, and a third table associating tags with items. See here:
[What is the most efficient way to store tags in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334183/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database)

**Using Array fields**
Where there is one table with items, descriptions, and an array field that stores tags

**Using JSON fields**
Where there is one table with items, descriptions, and an JSON field that stores tags. The django docs mention this uses JSONB: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

I am guessing that using JSON fields like the following:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tags = JSONField()
```

is the most efficient for reading data but I am not really sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one of theese is "most efficient", it really depends of what you're focused in.

**First** is classical relation approach, that provides consistency and normalisation. It also allows you to to retrieve complex information (i.e. *give me all items with a tag T)* pretty easy (but usually with a cost of joins). I think this should be your goto solution if you're using RDBMS.

**Second** and **third** (there mostly the same in your case) are easier for simple retrieve and store (i.e. *give me all tags of an item I*), but lead to a more work for keeping your data consistent and performing complex queries.

Comment: Any difference between the second and third option in terms of query speed?

Comment: @ccsv in most cases I'll bet on JSON with indexes (see GIN index, for example).