# Database design for tags or tagging

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, tagging

How are tags of an item stored in a database hassle-free?

Each item has multiple tags with it. I have read a few answers on an efficient way to do so :

1. [What is the most efficient way to store tags in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334183/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database)
2. [Recommended SQL database design for tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging/20871#20871)

But I think there is a better solution to this. Why can't we simply include tags as a long string for each item?

```
 Table : Brand_Shops
 Columns : brand_id, brand_name, content, tags
```

Example :

```
1 || Nike ||  shoes bags sports football soccer t-shirts track-pants
2 ||  GAP || wallets t-shirts jeans shoes perfumes
```

This does not have *atomicity* but completely suits the purpose of tagging. If a new brand has to be added, new tags can simply be added along with it. Because of this it will be very easy to fetch it as well. I don't understand why this is not an efficient solution.

Comment: Define efficient. Efficient for writing? efficient for reading? efficient for code maintenance?

Comment: Efficient for code maintainance and ease of use

Comment: Well IMHO, good code maintenance = simple code = don't use complicated code to split and append strings into one row. Just do a simple insert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why this is not an efficient solution.

It is inefficient because you have to retrieve and break/search that string for every query.

When you do something like (as mentioned in your links) `Three tables (one for storing all items, one for all tags, and one for the relation between the two)` then you can use the real power of a relational database, **the index**.

Instead of breaking each string into a tag or set of tags... that's already done; you just get the ones you want.  So, if you're searching for "shoes" then it goes straight there (using the index probably log n or faster) and returns both Nike and GAP.  It will do this no matter how many tags you have, no matter how many companies you have.

With the 3-table system you do all of the hard work up front and then just do lookups.

If you intend to run this locally or with a limited number of users your solution may be fine. It is also easier to code.
Once your queries start taking more than a few seconds you'll probably want to update your tagging system.  If you do it this way, write the search code separately in case you need to rip it out.

---

Question from comment:

> Can you give an example of a 3 table system that is normalized with
>   atomicity

Sure.
You've basically asked for Third Normal Form which is my usual goal. 
(I admit I often don't make 3NF because I optimize; e.g. storing a postal code with the addres - if you're out of school, that's a better choice)

```
--Sample SQL stackoverflow.com/questions/50793168/database-design-for-tags-or-tagging/50818392
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = N'ChrisC') 
BEGIN
 EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE SCHEMA [ChrisC] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]'
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ChrisC].[Brands]') AND type in (N'U'))
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ChrisC].[BrandTags]') AND type in (N'U'))
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ChrisC].[Tags]') AND type in (N'U'))
 BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE [ChrisC].[Brands]([pkBrand] [int] IDENTITY(101,1) NOT NULL,[Name] [varchar](40) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
  INSERT INTO [ChrisC].[Brands]([Name])VALUES('Nike'),('GAP')
  CREATE TABLE [ChrisC].[BrandTags]([pk] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[Brand] [int] NULL,[Tag] [int] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
  INSERT INTO [ChrisC].[BrandTags]([Brand],[Tag])VALUES
    (101,201),(101,202),(101,203),(101,204),(101,205),(101,206),(101,207),
    (102,208),(102,209),(102,203),(102,207),(102,210)
  CREATE TABLE [ChrisC].[Tags]([pkTag] [int] IDENTITY(201,1) NOT NULL,[Tag] [varchar](40) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
  INSERT INTO [ChrisC].[Tags]([Tag])VALUES
    ('bags'),('football'),('shoes'),('soccer'),('sports'),('track-pants'),('t-shirts'),('jeans'),('perfumes'),('wallets')
  SELECT b.[Name], t.Tag 
  FROM chrisc.Brands b 
  LEFT JOIN chrisc.BrandTags bt ON pkBrand = Brand
  LEFT JOIN chrisc.Tags t ON bt.Tag = t.pkTag
  WHERE b.[Name] = 'Nike'
  -- Stop execution here to see the tables with data
  DROP TABLE [ChrisC].[Brands]
  DROP TABLE [ChrisC].[BrandTags]
  DROP TABLE [ChrisC].[Tags]
 END
 IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = N'ChrisC') DROP SCHEMA [ChrisC]
END
```

Comment: Can you show with one example of how the tags would look like with a 3 table system in the Nike example. Because I feel, the rule of atomicity will be broken no matter what. And the database won't be normalized.

Comment: Done.  Let me know if you have questions (I used a custom schema which I hope isn't confusing)