# What's the best way to display the number of items related to tags?

Tags: php, mysql

After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging/20871#20871) recommendation regarding tags tables structure, I've implemented the following design:

```
Table: Item
Columns: ItemID, Title, Content

Table: Tag
Columns: TagID, Title

Table: ItemTag
Columns: ItemID, TagID
```

I'm facing another problem, I wanna display the number each tag appears in the system. What's the best way to do this in terms of search query / php code that will not cause a severe performance impact (tags count will appear for each item).

Thanks,

Roy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> select count(*)
> from ItemTag
> where TagId = X
> ```

is mySQL that will get it dynamically.

If you're worried about the performance hit, you should store a count in the tag table, and increment/decrement it when you tag or untag an item.

Comment: Storing the tag count in tag table will do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't store the count.  It's bound to get out of sync, and you'll have to do periodic queries to make sure it's correct.  Use the SELECT COUNT(*) solution, because it will always be accurate.  Enable the MySQL Query Cache as a transparent way to improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the following (SQL) will get all the tag titles and associated counts of how often they appear on items.

```
select tag.title, count(itemtag.tagid) 
from tag, itemtag
where itemtag.tagid = tag.tagid
group by tag.title
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Tag.Title, COUNT(Tag.TagID) AS TagCount
FROM ItemTag
LEFT JOIN Tag ON
(ItemTag.TagID = Tag.TagID)
GROUP BY Tag.Title
ORDER BY Tag.Title
```

Gives you a list of tags (ni alphabetical order) followed by the number of times they are used against an item. Unused tags do not appear.