# What's the sql scheme for supporting Tags system?

Tags: php, sql, tagging

i've coded a tiny forum software in php where people posts threads, and i want to support tags.

How many SQL tables should i make for this ? and briefly how the tags system will work?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging

Answer (score 4):

Basically you need tags(id, tag) table and tags-to-posts M:M relation table (tag_id,post_id). To select posts for a given tag

```
 select posts.* from posts, tags, post_tags
    where post_tags.post_id = posts.id
    and post_tags.tag_id = tags.id
    and tags.tag = "whatever_tag"
```

In response to the comment: a single table(tag,post) approach may appear "simpler", but it's not exactly scalable. What if you decide to add some extra info to your tag - like creation date or who created it. Or let users have "favorite tags", like here at SO - without a separate tags table this will be tricky.

In general, it's better to keep the database [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), even if it seems "complicated" at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks stereofrog, i'm wondering if doing 1 table will be better : tags(tagtitle,entryid) ?

Comment: I agree with stereofrog. the 2 table method is probably the best way to do this. keeps your tags table clean and unique also allows the M:M relationships

Answer (score 1):

There are some good reasoning and performance testing available in the article ["Tagsystems: performance tests"](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html)