# How to design the schema for something like StackOverflow questions tags?

Tags: database, database-design, tags

I have 3 plans:

**1, in questions table:**

```
question
------------------------------------
id title   content  ...       tags
------------------------------------
1  aaa     bbb      ...       tag1,tag2,tag3 (use , to split more tags)
```

**2, in tags table and split:**

```
tags
------------------------------------
id tag 
------------------------------------
1  tag1,tag2,tag3  (use , to split more tags)
```

**3, in tags table:**

```
tags
------------------------------------
id tag 
------------------------------------
1  tag1
2  tag2
3  tag3
```

I think that plan 3 is better, but what's your opinion?

Any other good ideas for this implementation?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please see [
How do you recommend implementing tags or tagging
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These patterns are called `mysqlicious`, `scuttle` and `toxi` (from the least to the most normalized).

They all have their benefits and drawbacks. You can read quite a good analysis here:

[http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/TagSchema (WayBackMachine Version)](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328011359/http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/TagSchema)

Note that `mysqlicious` heavily depends on your database's ability to perform `FULLTEXT` searches efficiently.

This means that for `MySQL` with `InnoDB` and for some other systems it's very impractical.

Answer (score 6):

The relationship between tags and content is [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many). What this means is that one tag can be associated with several units of content, and one unit of content can be associated with several tags.

To implement this in a database, you can use an auxiliary table called `ContentTags`. The relationship of `Content` to `ContentTags` is one-to-many; the relationship of `Tags` to `ContentTags` is one-to-many.

```
#Tags Table
Id   Text
 1  'Tag1'
 2  'Tag2'
 3  'Tag3'


#Content Table
Id   Content
 1   "some content"
 2   "other content"
 3   "more content"

#ContenTags Table
ContentId TagId
1         1
1         2
2         1
2         2
2         3
3         1
```

As you can see, the relationship is clearly reflected (content 1 is associated with tags 1 and 2; content 2 is associated with tags 1, 2, and 3; content 3 is only associated with tag 1)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how normalized you want your data to be.

Firstly, I cringe when I see an "id" column in a table that isn't unique. At least rename the column to "question_id".

Secondly, it depends on whether you want a quick listing of all tags defined. In which, case, you'd want a separate tag table defining the set of possible tags, and then an intermediate table between questions and tags that provided a many-to-many association.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is to create the one-many relations, that is you have one comment and multiple tags. From WIKI

> In database technology, a one-to-many (also known as to-many) relationships occurs when one entity is related to many occurrences in another entity. For example, one club has many members.

And the main concept in the database design is the [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Example).

So I'd do it like this.

```
comments
------------------------------------
id_comment title  content 
------------------------------------
12         aaa     bbb

tags
------------------------------------
id_tag comment_id tag 
------------------------------------
1      12         tag1
2      12         tag2
3      12         tag3
```

Comment: This kind of design will have **a lot of redundancy** in the filed **tag** because a lot of comment share the same tags. For example, we could have 1 million comments that are tagged "tag1".  By the way, If I accept the redundancy, then I see another problem: there is  no use by putting **id_tag** and **tag** at the same time in the **tags table**. We just need tag, **no need for id_tag if this table has already comment_id**.