# What is the best way to store meta tags?

Tags: database-design, tags

For example, let's take StackOverFlow's question tags. Would you store those separately in their own table with a many-to-many table linking questions and tags? Or is it best to store them as a coma-delimited list in the row of the question? Now assume the same scenario for a DVDs or games... I'm not sure how to go about this, and some advice would be appreciated.

My database is MySQL

Comment: multiple duplicates - the most relevant of which might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging,

Comment: In reality, any question of normalization (the multiple table route) vs denormalization (the single table route) will address your query (so to speak  :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe that having a table to resolve the m:m relationship would probably serve you best.  you can query on it, display the data without having to break out a comma-delemited field, and you can index the data.