# Tagging in php and mysql

Tags: php, tagging

My database schema for adding tags is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging)...

My question is how do I relate each tag with the current thread, so far I have done this:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO thread (title, content, author_id)
            VALUES ('$safe_title', '$safe_html_content', '$user_id')";
    $insert_thread = insert_Query($sql, $link);

    #   get the thread id:
    $thread_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

    #   insert the tags:
    foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {
        insert_Query("INSERT INTO tags (tag) 
        VALUES ('$tag')", $link);
    }

    #   connect tags to thread:
    $sql = "INSERT INTO thread_tags (thread_id, tag_id)
            VALUES ('$thread_id', )"; ## what to do here?
```

I want to know how I can fill in the ItemTag table (thread_tags in my case)... I can get the id of the current thread as shown in the $thread_id var, but how do I get the id of each tag and associate it with this thread?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why do you want to do it like that, but did you try this?

```
#   insert the tags:
foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    insert_Query("INSERT INTO tags (tag) 
    VALUES ('$tag')", $link);
    $tag_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    insert_Query("INSERT INTO thread_tags (thread_id, tag_id)
        VALUES ('$thread_id', $tag_id )",$link);
}
```