# Database design for tagging

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, tags, many-to-many

I want to implement a tagging system for entries in my database. I did some research and I guess that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging/20871#20871) is the best way to do it...however I'm not too experienced with MySQL (or PHP for that matter - I'm just making a sort of web app for fun) and thus I am confused on how to implement this.

Comment: and what do you expect for an answer now? Someone writing the SQL scripts?

Comment: I just wanted somebody to explain how that works.

Comment: The linked question already has lots of information on how that works. Can you please update your question with more specific details as to what you are looking for or where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your going to need to create the database in MySQL and then you will need to use PHP to create the user interface (HTML) and the code to access the database.  Since you are new I've listed out some getting started resources for each.  Good Luck!

Here's some resources for getting started with MySQL:

http://code.google.com/edu/tools101/mysql.html

http://a.parsons.edu/~kosoyj/2009/spring/pgte_5044/2009/03/24/mysql-101/

http://www.killerphp.com/mysql/

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/mysql_database_introduction_mysql_beginners_tutorial.php3

And some for basics/getting started with PHP:

http://devzone.zend.com/article/627

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/

[Learning PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819221/learning-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is ideal.  You should just start in on learning how to make a many-to-many relationship as the link explains.  But what are you using to edit PHP or try out queries?