# how to store keywords/tags

Tags: mysql, tags, keyword

I am building a web application where users will upload a file (XML format) with some data and some keywords/tags describing the data. This information will then be parsed and stored in MySQL database. Now i am not sure how to store these keywords/tags in the database and how to use them to retrieve appropriate data when the user enters keywords from the application frontend. I know i will have to build some kind of  ranking algorithm to rank the keywords but my application is still in its initial stages, so right now I am more concerned about how to retrieve data than the efficiency/relevance of retrieved data.

Please help me or guide me to a resource which can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite an open question, but if you need help implementing tags, see this for some great tips: [Recommended SQL database design for tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging)

Comment: what i am trying to ask is, how should i retrieve the appropriate data with the help of keywords. Will it be as simple as user entering a keyword and then i run a select query over the tags table to retrieve data which has been tagged with corresponding keyword?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it. This is all depending on what outcome you need. But as a start, you could do it like that.

Answer (score 3):

you can [store JSON array in mysql>=5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) for tags like below :

```
["tag1","tag2",...]
```

if you use an extra table for store tags , you need to join and search for adding a new tag , its bad way when we have too many tags in database !