# Tag System Implementation in Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, tags, tagging

Current Structure

**table [Tags]**

```
TagID
TagName
```

**table [Stores]**

```
StoreID
StoreName
StoreCategory
StoreTagID
```

this will only make the store have one tag , how can I implement it to allow more than one tag
I made tags group but not working also parsing but its usless like
tagid:tagname,tagid:tagname...... for the same row but not efficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you recommend implementing tags or tagging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to do this sort of thing is to create a third table e.g.

**table [Store_Tags]**

```
StoreID
TagID
```

Getting the tags for the Store then requires a join against Store_Tags to Tags e.g.

```
SELECT TagName FROM Tags INNER JOIN Store_Tags USING(TagID) WHERE StoreID = ?
```

An alternate approach would be to avoid using the Tag table and put the TagName directly in the Store_Tags table, it really depends how you intend to use the data.

Comment: So the idea behind the Store_Tags table is that it enables you to have multiple tags for the store. Whenever you want to add a new tag to the store you insert a new row with the StoreID and the TagID of the new tag.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow has all tags in separated DB table

```
Posts
  PostId
PostTags
  PostId
  TagId
Tgas
  TagId
  TagName
```

you can do similar

Comment: Have you a link to support that? Seems very unlikely to me as this can't be indexed making searches by tag inefficient.

Comment: Ah Ok. But notice they also have a `PostTags` table. That tag list is presumably a denormalised version of that.

Comment: @MartinSmith: ah yes, you're right. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/111595/ ... edited