# MySQL: tagging system

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, tagging

Assume I have a table that can have 0 or more tags:

```
TABLE: foo
- foo_id (PK)

TABLE: tag
- tag_id (PK)
- name

TABLE: foo_tag
- foo_tag_id (PK)
- foo_id (FK)
- tag_id (FK)
```

Questions:

1. The above is the most common and simplest way to implement a tagging system that I have seen. I do realize that there are potential problems with tagging systems in terms of scalability. Am I going to have that here?
2. Is there a way to do something like this in PHP or SQL: insert a new tag "bar". If "bar" does not exist, add it to the `tag` table and return the last inserted id. If "bar" does exist, do not add it and return the tag_id for it.
3. Is there a "proper" DB term for such a table describe in #2?

Comment: Almost same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging

Comment: Link possibly answers question #1. Questions #2 and #3 are important to me, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for a workaround to get the last ID on update:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

This will update the last insert id to the value of the updated value. In your case:

```
INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES ('bar')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag_id=LAST_INSERT_ID(tag_id);
```

`tag.name` needs to be a unique key.

Comment: `tag.name` will be UNIQUE. If `bar` is already a record and has a `tag_id` of, say, 10. When trying to insert `bar` again, what is returned? 10??? That's what I want.

Comment: Yes 10, `LAST_INSERT_ID(tag_id)` will be `LAST_INSERT_ID(10)` then, setting the last insert id to 10. Calling the `mysqli_insert_id` (or equivalent from the C API `last_insert_id()`) will return that 10 value then. Just test it. Note that this is MySQL specific.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't miss something, If your problem with this tagging system is **#2** in your question which is insert a new tag "bar" if it is not exists, then try using [INSERT IGNORE](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html) this will skip inserting the tag if it exist, and I think this is the term you are looking for in **#3** like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Tag set name = 'bar';
```

Comment: Any "gotchas" I need to worry about with `INSERT IGNORE`? And for #3, I was looking for a "proper" term to refer to such tables. For example, I've heard people call "foo_tag" as "mapping table." Looking for something similar.

Comment: I think there are no "gotchas" for using it just see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update ,and for #3 If you just asking about naming convention I think it might be as SO named it just `Tags` see the Db Structure on the right in this page: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new.

Answer (score 0):

**#2** I would set **unique key** to tag.name. Assuming you have auto increment on tag_id, you may try this:

```
function tagId($tag) {
  mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO tag SET name='$tag'");
  if(mysql_affected_rows()) return mysql_insert_id();
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE name='$tag'");
  if(!$result) return null;
  $data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  if($data) return $data[0];
}
```