# Content Tagging

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a **small Web App to categorize** certain type of YouTube **videos**, when users submits a video they will choose what **categories this video falls under** and they will **tag it with ready-made tags**, for example:
Video one - Category: Ad - Tags: cute, funny, has animal in it. 
I'm trying to sketch my Database for that (I'm using MySQL), so far I have two ideas.

**Idea 1:**
Table Videos with `ID` and `Category` columns, another table Tags with `ID` and `Tag` columns while `Videos.ID` and `Tags.ID` are linked together. So when the user tries to filter search results by tags, the query will have more conditions (`AND Tag = 'something' AND Tag = 'other thing'`).

**Idea 2:**
One table Videos with `Category` and `Tags` columns, tags are stored as a string separated by commas, when the user tries to filter search results by tags, the query will more conditions (`AND Tags LIKE '%something%' AND Tags LIKE '% other thing%`).

 So the **question is**: Is there any better method? I already think that the 1st one is wasteful (Each video might have up to 40 ready-made tags) and the 2nd one is clumsy. If not, which one do you think is better?

Comment: Duplicate of [how to implement tagging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a additional table linking `video id` and `tag id` together is the correct solution. Filtering is done by creating additional `INNER JOIN` conditions. A comma separated list just won't do - it drastically limits your selection and query possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1 looks good. Creating a separate table for storing tags helps in selection.