# wanted selection of tags just like asp.net or stackoverflow,example?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

At every question posting on websites like ASP.NET and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) there's an option to select tags for questions. These tags are from a database, I need exactly the same solution fir my website. Can anyone suggest some an example?

I am using ASP.NET with a SQL Server database.

Comment: You could store already entered tags in a database, then use jQuery autocomplete when people are typing in the box to show up possible matches. There is a demo at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple that does this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you recommend implementing tags or tagging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging)

Comment: @KevinB  yes I see this example but I am not good at jquery/js , please just post a way to assign 'var availableTags=' to any hidden feild or C# var or C# string ,thanks

Comment: I tried the source in my asp.net page , but its not showing suggestions as in source link you sent

Comment: Issue is resolved everyone , the answer I marked is exactly the solution , I modified it according to my DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution present on internet ,exactly I wanted 
https://github.com/harindaka/ASPTokenInput
Its uses the jqueryui API but it modifies it to fit perfectly to be able to adjust with C# code , to get the text on fly it process a url of an aspx page like a web service and retrieves the results from db on every key down event . you can code every thing you want in suggestion their ItemList.aspx.cs code   and there you go , perfect harmony of C# code with power of Jquery

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

[**This**](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/09/09/Tag-Editor-Field-using-jQuery-similar-to-StackOverflow.aspx) may be the thing you wanted and then you can use jqueryUI autocomplete to achieve the autocomplete behavior as suggested by [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b)

for storing tags in database definitely you have to manage it in database based on TAG -User relationship

Comment: yes you are right , I saw this but one please ,I am not good at js/jquery , please tell me the way to assign values: [
            'javascript',
            'css',
            'jquery'
        ]

Comment: to any hidden field or C# var or C# string

Answer (score 0):

While the server-side code is PHP, [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-jquery-powered-tag-cloud/) shows you how you can build your own jQuery powered tag cloud that gets its data from the server (either the database or some other source).