# Tag synonyms in DB schema with three columns

Tags: sql, data-modeling, database-schema, tagging, datamodel

Assume you have the same data model as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871/653379).

```
Table: Item
Columns: ItemID, Title, Content

Table: Tag
Columns: TagID, Title

Table: ItemTag
Columns: ItemID, TagID
```

If you want to have tag synonyms similarly as are on `stackoverflow`, where would you place this information in the data model? Would you add only one attribute with comma-separated list of synonyms or would you transform a data model a little?

How  the `SQL` statement for inserting new item would look like? Will the new item be connected with all the synonyms or only with one main tag and in the code we have to detect that this is a synonym?

Which approach would you recommend for smooth **inserting**, **deleting** and **searching by tag** operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Tag` table and add a `TagSynonym` table:

```
Table: Tag
Columns: TagID

Table: TagSynonym
Columns: TagID, Title
```

The `TagSynonym.TagID` would be an FK to `Tag(TagID)` and the `Title` would be the PK.

---

If you also want to have a "MainSynonym" tag, then you could use this:

```
Table: Tag
Columns: TagID

Table: TagSynonym
Columns: TagID, Title

Table: TagMainSynonym
Columns: TagID, Title
```

with `TagMainSynonym(TagID)` being the PK and `TagMainSynonym(TagID, Title)` being an FK to `TagSynonym(TagID, Title)`.

It may look overdue but a simple operation like merging two tags will only need a simple `UPDATE` (one row) on the `Tag.TagID` and the cascading effects will do the rest (in 3 tables)

Comment: I was considering using only one the table Tag with "synonym" column which would contain the name of the main synonym or "main" if it's the main synonym itself. Is it better to have two tables?

Comment: The `ItemTag.TagID` has to be a Foreign Key to a `SomeTable(TagID)` where `(TagID)` is the Primary Key. But with `TagID` you want (now) to be identifying all synonyms, correct? So, I don't see a way without adding another table.

Comment: Now, I see. With two tables the implementation of inserting, deleting and searching by tag will be more pure.