# Database Design - Questions, Answers, Tags

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, tags

I have been reviewing the questions and answers here: [Recommended SQL database design for tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging) ,
and I understand the general design of the database, but how does it work? For instance, say I have the design setup like this:

`Table:Questions
Columns: QuestionID, Title, Content`

```
Table: Tags
Columns: TagID, Title
```

Table: QuestionTag 
Columns: QuestionID, TagID

Now when a user creates a new question, would I insert that question into the Questions table with the QuestionID set to auto increment? Then do the same for the Tags?

But then how do I match the QuestionID to the TagID in the QuestionTag table if I don't necessarily know what the ID is upon insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's mysql, the last ID can be traced using [`MYSQL_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html)