# Any better way of saving tags in db using commas?

Tags: php, database, tags

Currently I am using commas "," to save tags as text and when I neeed them to process and use somewhere I need to explode the string e.g. "usa,canada,crime,Toronto,music,fall".

I was thinking if there is any better way ( less resource and time-consuming friendly ) of doing this tag or is this the only solution that everybody use.

**EDIT: 
I have a small project, without tags managment in admin. I do not need to have three tables just for tags in db. I am just looking for some more clever solution how to save and explode the tags from the saved strings in the database.**

Comment: Previously asked: [how do you recommend implementing tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging).

Comment: Commas is never the way to save in database...

Comment: if you have one column what would be your suggestion? I have a simple blog no need to three tables just for tags.

Comment: @Derfder `no need to three tables just for tags` - you asked if there's a better way, well, that's the better way. If you are certain this is not the answer you are looking for, that presumably means you already *know* the answer you are looking for, in which case why are you asking the question?

Comment: "you asked if there's a better way, well, that's the better way" for a bigger project, yes, but in my case not. I will update original post so it is clear I have a small website with no tags managment in admin.

Comment: What do you have against using three tables? You realize you might as well not use a database at all but a flat file instead?

Comment: You're asking for a better way but rejecting solutions because they don't suggest what you're already doing. What's the point of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the three-table approach, really! Really really!

Otherwise, how will you query items that have tag "usa" without also getting items tagged with "usable"? `LIKE %usa%` will return both.

See this for a discussion on three methods for implementing tags in db:
http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html

**EDIT** in response to comment:

> Commas, commas, commas...

Commas won't help won't help won't help. Example tag field: `culture,usa`. How will you `LIKE` this?

You could arguably save tags in format: `,culture,usa,` (stating and ending with a comma).

Imho that will bring along some special cases and it will in the end become more complicated that the three-table approach.

Comment: I've in multiple places seen that people suggest a three tables solution. Why three isn't two enough? Say one table named articles and one named tags. Articles includes id, topic and author. Tags include id, tag and articleId. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @Oskwish Because with only 2 tables you only have a 1-to-many relationship. A tag can only point to a single article.

Comment: Ahh okay, but, let's say that you usei only 2 tables and store the same tag multiple times for different articles. Doesn't that actually make you save space compared to storing 3 additional values in another table?

Comment: @Oskwish Yeah I guess you could do that. When listing all items tagged with "usa" you do a `GROUP BY` on tag values. With the 3-table schema you save yourself from the `GROUP BY` and could do some advanced things with simpler SQL. But that's not relevant for OP's question. I am wondering whether 2-table or 3-table results in simpler SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the tags are related to the some item (users, blog etc), there is a simple way to do it

```
Table_Tags 
{ 
   tag_id:index for the table entries,
   item_id, 
   tag_code: usa,
   source: app_system, comment, fb, twitter etc
   <other audit fields>
}
```

while processing the item/populating the item, the tags can be populated as well.

hope this helps