# Scaling content tags based on popularity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tagging

I'm implementing a basic tagging system using the database structure outlined in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging).

I would like a single page that displays all the tags, where each tag is visually scaled depending on its popularity.

Are there any JavaScript or CSS libraries that already offer this kind of functionality? Or do I need to roll my own with (already using Bootstrap and JQuery)...for example, SQL `COUNT`ing the number of records for each tag, and using some function of this for font-size?

Answer (score 0):

I have used for my webstie https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud , its pretty good and easy to use.
You can check an example here: http://www.lucaongaro.eu/demos/jqcloud/