# Better query to add OR implementing tags or tagging

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create create a tagging system and somehow I have created it but I think there is a better way to do it! 
Im following Yaakov Ellis suggestion given here [Recommended SQL database design for tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging?lq=1)

My php code

```
    <?php
    //checks to see if form is submitted or not
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['short']) && isset($_POST['detail']) && isset($_FILES['cover']) && isset($_POST['secret']) && isset($_POST['bulb'])) :
        //checks the required field
        if (!empty($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['short']) && !empty($_POST['detail']) && !empty($_FILES['cover']['name']) && ($_POST['secret'] === '****secret****') && is_array($_POST['bulb'])) {
                $title = $_POST['title'];
                $short = $_POST['short'];
                $detail = $_POST['detail'];
                $bulb = $_POST['bulb']; //Array Checkbox -> Its a checkbox

            //Time Processing
                    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta"); //Time Zone
                    $timestamp = time();    //Current Time in seconds
                $date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $timestamp);   //Current time
                $time = strftime("%H:%M:%S", $timestamp);   //Current date
            //Time Processing Ends

            //Image Processing
                    $cover = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
                    $cover_tmp_name = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
                    $cover_format = substr($cover , -4);
                $cover_name = md5($cover).'.'.$cover_format;
                $cover_img_path = '../images/cover/';
            //Image Processing Ends

                if (($cover_type == 'image/jpeg' || $cover_type == 'image/gif' || $cover_type == 'image/png')) {

                    $query_for_news_insert = "INSERT INTO `news` (
                                        `id` ,
                                        `title` ,
                                        `short_line` ,
                                        `detail` ,
                                        `cover` ,
                                        `date` ,
                                        `time`
                                        )
                                        VALUES (
                                        NULL , 
                                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."', 
                                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($short)."', 
                                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($detail)."', 
                                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($cover_name)."', 
                                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."', 
                                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($time)."'
                                        );
                                        ";

                    $run_query_for_news_insert = mysql_query($query_for_news_insert);

    /**************  Step 1 of 3 for inserting tags **************************/
                    $query_to_get_id_of_news_inserted = "SELECT `id`
                                                         FROM `news`
                                                         WHERE `date` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."'
                                                         AND `time` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($time)."'";

                    $run_query_to_get_id_of_news_inserted = mysql_query($query_to_get_id_of_news_inserted);
                    $returned_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query_to_get_id_of_news_inserted);
                $news_id = array_shift($returned_id);   //News id which will be used in step 3


    /**************  Step 2 of 3 for inserting tags *************************/
                    foreach ($bulb as $select => $value) :

                        $query_to_get_tag_id = "SELECT `tag_id`
                                             FROM `newstag` 
                                             where `tag_cat` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";

                        $run_query_to_get_tag_id = mysql_query($query_to_get_tag_id);
                        $rows_returned_from_query_to_get_tag_id = mysql_num_rows($run_query_to_get_tag_id);
                        if ($rows_returned_from_query_to_get_tag_id == '1') {

                            $returned_tag_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query_to_get_tag_id);
                $tag_id = array_shift($returned_tag_id);   //Tag id which will be used in step 3


    /***************         Step 3 of 3 for inserting tags ******************/
                            $query_to_insert_itemTag = "INSERT INTO `newsitemtag` (
                                                       `id` ,
                                                       `tag_id` ,
                                                       `news_id`
                                                        )
                                                        VALUES (
                                                        NULL , '".mysql_real_escape_string($tag_id)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($news_id)."'
                                                        )";
                            $run_query_to_insert_itemTag = mysql_query($query_to_insert_itemTag);

                        }
                    endforeach;

                    move_uploaded_file($cover_tmp_name,$cover_img_path.$cover_name); //Transfer file from temp location to permanent location

                    echo 'Success';

                } // End of if statement which checks the image type
        } else {
            echo 'Failed';
        }

    endif;
    ?>
```

As you can see that the greater the number of element in array (here $bulb) then my code will run hell lot off query.

Comment: You should better check the file name extension of the uploaded file, otherwise one could upload a `.php` file.

Comment: For create date better use [TIMESTAMP field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Answer (score 0):

to speed this up you should try an insert select

```
" INSERT INTO `newsitemtag` (`id` ,  `tag_id` , `news_id` )
  SELECT NULL , n.id ,".$news_id."
  FROM `newstag` n  where n.tag_cat in ('".join("','",$bulb)."') ";
```

of course you should do the sanitation as you did with your example

to do that you should check out  http://php.net/array_walk

http://php.net/manual/de/function.join.php

Answer (score 0):

1) For get id by last insert field use [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

2) Then the "code add tag" will be like this;

```
<?php
  /* code */
  if (mysql_query($query_for_news_insert)) {
    $nid  = mysql_insert_id(); 
    $tags = $_POST['bulb'];
    if (!empty($tags)) {
      # get all avalible tags
      # Don't use subqueries bcz all tags can be fake
      $query  = 'SELECT `tag_id` WHERE `tag_cat` IN ('. implode(',', $tags) .')';
      $res    = mysql_query($query);
      $values = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $values[] = '('. $row[0] .', '. $nid .')';
      }

      if (!empty($values)) {
        # don't use NULL and `id` if `id` is auto-increment field
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `newsitemtag` (`tag_id`, `news_id`) VALUES ('. implode(',', $values) .')';
        mysql_query($query);
      }
    }
   }
?>
```

Comment: don't you think that adding tag id in html side will be little bit insecure??

Comment: You use checkbox for select tag. If you use checkbox, radio button, or select, why not use real id? it's right.

Comment: its not about using real id. its about passing those value to db without verifying that the tag id actually exist.

Comment: Yes this it's insecurity, but using mysql_query insecurity too. (Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for protect queries). p/s/ code reworked

Comment: PDO is good but it is tough to code atleast for me.
is there any other way??

Comment: Or you can try to protect sql, itself. It's bad way.[filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php)

Comment: it's bad. Example replace some words or special strings: preg_replace('/[^\'"@%]|SELECT|UNION/ui', '', $sql); But sometimes char ' or " is needed, and regexp need rework. Always what is created must be checked. Security issue can be everywhere.

Comment: [faq](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You can protect variabel by escape quotes. But injection can be other. Like a oreder: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY $var. Or can be a 'like' expression: SELECT * FROM table WEHRE col LIKE "$var". Or mistake in sql-query SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $var.