# How to write model for tags database

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, database-schema

I want to create an object with tags and categories. I read on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871 that the tags schema should be like this,

```
> Table: Item Columns: ItemID, Title, Content
> 
> Table: Tag Columns: TagID, Title
> 
> Table: ItemTag Columns: ItemID, TagID
```

However, I want to associate every tags with a category.
What I want is an item can have only one category and multiple tags. And the tags are also associated with/group in the category.

I am not very clear how to use the model relationship, this is what I come up with:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class ItemTag(models.Model):
    itemid = models.ForeignKey(Item) #not sure if this is correct to use foreignkey
    tagid = models.ForeignKey(Tags)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

#not sure how to do this category grouping
class CategoryTags(models.Model):
    catid = models.Foreignkey(Category)
    tagid = models.Foreignkey(Tags)
```

There are plenty tags will be created, and it will be use in the search keyword for the Items. Not sure if this is the best idea to cope with.

Comment: Why not use `django-tagit`? At least you can have a look at their [`models.py`](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/develop/taggit/models.py) to see how to setup models for tagging.

Comment: I am new to django, there are many things that I don't know. But thanks for the recommendation, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your task description (An item can have only one category and multiple tags. And the tags are also associated with/group in the category.) I'd suggest the following schema:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    # the tag belongs to a category
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    # the item belongs to one category 
    # if having a category is required please remove blank=True
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True) 
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
```

[ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) is a many-to-one relationship. In your case many items belong to one category.

See also [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) field.