# Retrieving tag names from tag-post table in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance

first I was wondering which would be the best implementation of tags and categories in my database. So I found in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging) that the best way would be like this:

```
Table: Item
Columns: ItemID, Title, Content

Table: Tag
Columns: TagID, Title

Table: ItemTag
Columns: ItemID, TagID
```

Now I am wondering how I'd get the best performance showing information from the database. So, lets say I made a select and now I have a bunch of "ItemID"s and want to know which tags these elements have. So what do you think of building this algorithm like:

```
For each ItemID
   Do whatever I wanna do first
   SELECT Tag ID from table ItemTag Where ItemID
   For each unique TagID 
      SELECT Title from table Tag Where TagID
      Print on screen tag name
```

Do you think this is a good solution? Is there another simple, but with a better performance way for doing it?

Comment: No effect to performance but, use TagName instead of Title for Table Tag.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `join` and `group_concat()`:

```
select itemId, group_concat(t.title)
from ItemTag it join
     tag t
     on it.TagId = t.TagId
group by itemId;
```

You can add a `where` clause if you want the tags only for a specific item.