# Is a two table solution a performant and scalable solution to implement tagging in Postgres 9.5?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema

### Background

I work for a real estate technology company. An upcoming project involves building out functionality to allow users to affix tags/labels (plural) to a MLS listing (real estate property). The second requirement is to allow a user to search by one or more tags. We won't be dealing with keeping track of counts or building word clouds or anything like that.

### Solutions Researched

I found [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging) and think the solution is pretty straightforward and have attempted to adapt some ideas from it below. Also, I understand that JSONB support is much better in 9.5 and it *may* be a possibility. If you have any insight here I'd love to hear your thoughts as well in an answer.

### Attempted Solution

**Table**: Tags

**Columns**: ID, OwnerID, TagName, CreatedDate

---

**Table**: TaggedItems

**Columns**: ID, TagID (references above), PropertyID, CreatedDate, (Possibly some denormalized data to assist with presenting search results; property name, original listor, etc.)

---

Inserting new tags should be straightforward. Searching tags should also be straightforward since the user will select one or multiple tags from a searchable dropdown, thus affording me access to the actual TagID which I can use to query the `TaggedItems` table. When showing the full profile view for a listing, I can use it's PropertyID and the UserID to query my tables for the existence of one or more Tags to display in the view.

**Edit**: It's probably worth noting that we don't keep an entire database of properties, we access them via an API partner; hence the two table solution and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Nth normalize you would actually use 3 tables.

1 Property/Listing
2 Tags
3 CrossReferenceBetween the Two

The 3rd table creates a many to many relationship between the other 2 tables.

In this case only the 3 rd table would carry both the tagid and the property.

Going with 2 tables if fine too depending on how large of use you have as a small string won't bloat your databse too much.

I would say that it is strongly preferable to separate the tags to a separate table when you need to do lookups and more on it.  Otherwise you have to have a delimited list which then what happens if a user injects a delimiter into their tag value?  Also how do you plan on searching the delimited list?  You will constantly expand that to a table or use regex and the regex might give you false positives as "some" will match "some" and "something" depending on how you write your code.......