# An effective way to query a collection to search and count items by tag in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, nosql

Suppose I have an items table in Cassandra like this:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
id uuid,
tags set<text>,
name text,
available boolean,
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

So I have basically items with tags, the number of tags is unknown and can reach up to few hundreds and different items may share some tags. I have two requirements:

- I want to query the number of items which contain a specific set
  of tags, for example I want to know the number of items with tag1 or
  tag2, or tag200 in their tags column.
- I want to update all items
  which contain a specific set of tags (found in requirement 1), so for
  example I want to set `available = true` for all items with tag1 or
  tag2, or tag200 in their tags column.

These can be done using Spark, or a secondary index, but I don't want to use that and would like to explore if these can be done using pure CQL effectively. So maybe I have to start with a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE itemsByTag (
id uuid,
tag text,
tags set<text>,
name text,
available boolean,
PRIMARY KEY ((tag),id);
```

But this table can give me the same item twice or more (say that item1 has tag1 and tag2 and tag200 then I will get item1 three times when I query the previous table by tag) Also, how to construct a suitable table for a Cassandra counter table to satisfy requirement 1?

in RDBMS this is done using three tables as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging), the question is how to denormalize this effectivly in Cassandra.