# How to join based on json column in Laravel QueryBuilder

Tags: php, laravel

posts table

```
    |id|value|
    |1 |hoge |
    |2 |fuga |
    |3 |piyo |
```

some_posts table

```
    |id|post_ids|
    |1 |[1, 2]  |
    |2 |[1]     |
    |3 |[1, 2, 3]|
```

I want to join using **QueryBuilder**.
What should I do?

That was not possible.

```
DB::table('some_posts')
  ->join('posts', 'some_posts.post_ids', 'posts.id');
```

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not
>   exist: json = integer\n LINE 1: ...ts" inner join "posts" on
>   "some_posts"."post_ids" = "posts"....\n
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need
>   to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select "some_posts".* from
>   "some_posts" inner join "posts" on "some_posts"."post_ids" =
>   "posts"."id" where "some_posts"."some_id" = 384)

Thank you,

Comment: Why wasn't that possible? What error/unwanted result did you get?

Comment: thanks comment!
I added error description

SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = integer\n
LINE 1: ...ts" inner join "posts" on "some_posts"."post_ids" = "posts"....\n
                                                             ^\n
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select "some_posts".* from "some_posts" inner join "posts" on "some_posts"."post_ids" = "posts"."id" where "some_posts"."some_id" = 384)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by **whereJsonContains** in laravel.
Join with a condition which looks similar to this.

```
$query->whereJsonContains('options->languages', ['en', 'de'])
```

> You should not save the ids in JSON object.

Comment: > should not save the ids in JSON object.
yes, that's right... sry...
Could you tell me how to use whereJsonContains in a join closure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection in the `Post` model

**Post.php**

```
Class Post extends model

public function somePosts()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('some_posts`, 'post_ids');
}
```

Then, change this

```
DB::table('some_posts')
->join('posts', 'some_posts.post_ids', 'posts.id');
```

to

```
Post::with('somePosts')->get();
```

Comment: thank you answer.

but, I want to do it with QueryBuilder.
Originally I wrote in Eloquent Model, but there was a performance problem with Eloquent.

Comment: Try to use `ANY` like this `->join('posts', 'some_posts.post_ids', ANY('posts'.id);

Comment: Is there a method definition called ANY in Laravel?
I couldn't find it.
please tell me the namespace...

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043739/setting-up-foreign-key-with-an-array-of-integers