# Can I store and arrary in string format in mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, schema

or better, is this good practice?

I would like to store bookmarks, each bookmark a row.  I want a tag column that is an array in string format that hold the hierarchy of tags that define it.  For example:

```
url | tag
'stackoverflow.com', '[faves, internet, QandA]'
```

My current table is below, and I just want to modify the `tag` column to hold the array in string form.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: No, it's not a good practice at all. By storing your tags in a string you will lose certain abilities such as using the tags in a conditional. Consider creating a new table for tags.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not usually a good idea to store a comma-separated list in a string.

Exception: if your queries always treat the whole string as a string, and you have no need to use SQL expressions to search for individual elements, then there's no harm in doing this.

In SQL, it's better to treat each column as a single scalar value, not an array. Working with data gets awkward and inefficient if you treat a column as something that can be broken down into sub-parts.

For your tags, you should have a one-to-many tag table so that each bookmark can be referenced by many tags, one per row in the tag table.

Or really, a lookup table of tags, then a many-to-many table mapping bookmarks to their tags.

```
CREATE TABLE Tag (
  tag_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  tag VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE BookmarkTag (
  bookmark_id INT NOT NULL,
  tag_id      INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (bookmark_id, tag_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (bookmark_id) REFERENCES Bookmark(bookmark_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES Tag(tag_id)
);
```

This gives you a lot more flexibility, for example:

- No limit to the number of tags per bookmark
- Easy to search for a specific tag
- Easy to count how many tags per bookmark
- Easy to prevent duplicates, control the tags allowed, delete a given tag from every bookmark that uses it, etc.

See also my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: If you have answered this question already in another question, then you should vote to close the question as a duplicate, you should not answer it again.

Comment: @Shadow, questions are not identical, even if the answer is the same. If I were to close the question as a duplicate, I'm likely to get complaints from other users saying that I closed it inappropriately.

Comment: They are. Both ask if it is a goid idea to store data in a delimited format within a single field.

Comment: It's a judgement call. I'm well aware of how to use Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry.  What is the suggestion for the table structure?

Comment: @stackoverflow I updated my answer with an example. But for what it's worth, this has been answered years ago too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging