# Searching dataset by multiple tags

Tags: c++, qt, search

Maybe the title of this question is a little bit odd because I simply have no idea what I'm looking for.

I have some data e.g. a string and multiple tags associated with it. Now I would like to have the ability to search through my data with a string.

> Edit: **The Problem is not the string comparison or the substring
>   search!** The Problem is the connection from the result to the data
>   object.

Here a Movie example:

```
"Title1" tags: "genre1" "genre2" "actor1" "actor2"
"Title2" tags: "genre2" "actor2" "actor3"
"Title3" tags: "genre2" "genre3" "actor1" "actor3"

Search for "genre2" -> "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"
Search for "Title1" -> "Title1"
Serach for "actor1" -> "Title1", "Title3"
```

Other examples:

- YouTube: Search for a Video ...
- Amazon: Search for "tv" but "tv" does not have to be in the title.

The only thing in my mind is a multimap pointing to a list of all possibilities. Then I have to compare the search string with all keys and tada. But I can not believe that this is a good solution because I would have an insane amount of lists...

Can anyone give me an idea of what I'm looking for and maybe how I can implement this? I use c++ with Qt. I don't know if Qt could help me in any way.

**Edit:** I could add all keyword together like this:

```
"Title1 genre1 genre2 actor1 actor2"
"Title2 genre2 actor2 actor3"
"Title3 genre2 genre3 actor1 actor3"
```

Create a map with this key to the data object. Then I only have to do a string search and get all strings where the search string is a substring of the key.

But is this a good solution? What if I want to prioritize a match in the title?

Comment: Have you considered an actual database? Perhaps sqlite?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, but at the moment I'm not sure if I need one.

Comment: I think the best way to solve this is `suffix tree` or `suffix array`. If you use `suffix tree`, use list of indices of all titles corresponding to a string in the leaf.

Comment: @abdullah Hm, I looked into it but it looks like this would only help me to detect something like this: "ctor" -> "actor1", "actor2", "actor3". But in the end, I would like to have all 3 titles in this case. Or is it better to consider only an exact match of a tag as a tag search and all others as a title search?

Comment: @Darkproduct You should test for exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Severel Month later I decided to work on this problem again and finally, I have a solution. It took me ~ 4 h to get everything working. I'm using now Toxi-Tagging with SQLite in Qt. I had this Idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging) and looked also into other possibilities. Here is a page with multible options and a small comparison: [Link](http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/04/24/Tags-Database-schemas/)

Here is my Solution:
Create the Database and add Values to it. Then you can do a simple substring search like this:

```
SELECT Data.* FROM Data 
INNER JOIN DataTag ON DataTag.DataID=Data.ID 
INNER JOIN Tag ON DataTag.TagID=Tag.ID WHERE Tag.Tag LIKE "%substring%" 
GROUP BY Data.ID
```

Sidenote: If your Tag list is really large it is probably beneficial to use FTS3 or FTS4. Here is [more info](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

Create Database:

```
QString scom;
QSqlQuery query;

scom = "CREATE TABLE Data ("
       "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
       "Data1 VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
       "Data2 INTEGER NOT NULL,"
       "Data3 INTEGER NOT NULL);";

if(!query.exec(scom))
{
    qDebug() << "Error creating table Data";
}

scom = "CREATE TABLE Tag ("
       "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
       "Tag VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE);";

if(!query.exec(scom))
{
    qDebug() << "Error creating table Tag";
}

scom = "CREATE TABLE DataTag ("
       "DataID INTEGER,"
       "TagID INTEGER,"
       "FOREIGN KEY(DataID) REFERENCES Data(ID)"
       "FOREIGN KEY(TagID) REFERENCES Tag(ID));";

if(!query.exec(scom))
{
    qDebug() << "Error creating table DataTag";
}

scom = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON Tag (Tag)";

if(!query.exec(scom))
{
    qDebug() << "Error could not create index on Tag Tag";
}
```

Adding Values to the Database:

```
QString scomadddata, scomaddtag, scomadddatatag, scomsearchtag;
QSqlQuery query;

scomadddata = "INSERT INTO Data (ID, Data1, Data2, Data3) "
              "VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)";

query.prepare(scomadddata);
query.addBindValue(data1);
query.addBindValue(data2);
query.addBindValue(data3);

if(!query.exec())
{
    qDebug() << "Error adding values to Data";
    qDebug() << query.lastError();
}

QVariant dataid = query.lastInsertId();

scomsearchtag = "SELECT ID FROM Tag WHERE Tag = ";
scomaddtag = "INSERT INTO Tag (ID, Tag) VALUES (NULL, ?)";
scomadddatatag = "INSERT INTO DataTag (DataID, TagID) VALUES (?, ?)";

for(int i = 0; i < tags.count(); ++i)
{
    QVariant tagid;

    // Search if Tag allready exists
    if(!query.exec(scomsearchtag + "\"" + tags[i] + "\""))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error searching for Tag";
        qDebug() << query.lastError();
    }

    if(query.next())
    {
        tagid = query.value(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // Add Tag to Tag Table
        query.prepare(scomaddtag);
        query.addBindValue(tags[i]);

        if(!query.exec())
        {
            qDebug() << "Error adding values to Tag";
            qDebug() << query.lastError();
            continue;
        }

        // Get Tag ID
        tagid = query.lastInsertId();
    }

    // Link Tag ID with Data ID
    query.prepare(scomadddatatag);
    query.addBindValue(dataid);
    query.addBindValue(tagid);

    if(!query.exec())
    {
        qDebug() << "Error adding values to DataTag";
        qDebug() << query.lastError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If its a a lot of data, or you expect to migrate the data to another computer, I'd go with Qt's built in SQL functionality.

Comment: I don't expect the data to be transferred to another computer because it is only a collection of other data in the local file system.