# Is it a good idea to model keywords as value object in Product aggregate?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregate, value-objects

I have product aggregate which has several keywords to help for searching products. I have modeled it as following:

```
public class Product : Entity<Guid,Product> , IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid AccountId { get; protected set; }

    public string Title { get; protected set; }

    public DateTimeOffset AddingDate { get; protected set; }

    public decimal Price { get; protected set; }

    public string Brand { get; protected set; }

    public string Description { get; protected set; }

    public IList<Keyword> Keywords { get; protected set; }
}

public class Keyword : ValueObject<Keyword> 
{
    public Keyword(string title) 
    {
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public string Title { get; protected set; }
 }
```

Depending on [entity-vs-value-object-the-ultimate-list-of-differences](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/01/11/entity-vs-value-object-the-ultimate-list-of-differences/) Value objects have several characteristics:

1.Two value objects considered equal if they have the same attribute values.
2.Value objects have zero lifespan.
3.Value objects are immutable.

But for searching purposes I will store keywords as many-to-many with product table as recommended [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871/8618595) instead of comma-separated string.

So I am aiming to model keyword as value object because I don't care about its identity(whether it's auto generated integer or Guid) and for marking two keyword as equal by their attribute(which is here Title).

My question is: Should I model keyword as value object or entity depending on the scenario above and why?

**Edit:**

Depending on the article I provided above:

> Don’t introduce separate tables for value objects, just inline them into the parent entity’s table.

Keyword should be considered as Entity(But I think that domain and database models should not depend on each other)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd bother even having the keywords in the domain.

They seem to be a classifier of sorts (in quite a conceptual sense).  If I *did* have it in the domain I'd have a simple `string` list.  But again, those keywords probably have very little business value and probably don't have any rules associated with them.  I'm guessing they aid in searching for a particular product.

You may want to "manage" the keywords separately on your UI anyway.

You could take this even further and quite easily have a generic (perhaps sub-domain) `Tag`/`Keyword` "repository" where any `Id` (say a `Guid`) can have a list of keywords or tags.  In this way you could associate keywords with anything really.

To take this to the extreme a generic classification system may even be useful... but that is another topic :)

Comment: yea I agree with u that they don't have any business rules but they are part of the Product aggregate and in the UI when a vendor needs to add a new product to his store he should provide them (amazon doing this)

Comment: Your UI could gather all kinds of data but how you assemble, store, and relate those bits can be designed in various ways.  It is quite possible to get the keywords and plonk them in some data store that relates the product to the keyword.  But the design should just be sensible.  If you were, for instance, going to relate keywords to various entities (my example, not yours) then having a list of keywords on each entity class would become somewhat of a pain IMHO.

Comment: Did you mean for example I should check product invariants then after adding it, I can add the related keywords using a repository so keywords outside product aggregate?? and why do you mind having keywords as many-to-many with product table?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.  You can add the keywords separately and perhaps even maintain then separately.  Much as here on SO where my "Watched Tags" are maintained separately from my profile.  They are certainly still linked to my profile though and may even be on the profile page but I don't need to edit my profile in order to maintain that list.  I don't mind having keywords as many-to-many :) --- it will turn out that way but since a keyword isn't an entity it isn't *really* many-to-many in the traditional sense.  A product simply has a list of keywords...

Comment: A tag could very well be an entity though. On SO they are actually. They have a description which may change over time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could define predicates as arguments for searching methods. And put predicates regarding with an aggregate in the module of the aggregate  (module as a DDD concept), I.e. java package, or namespace in your case (not sure if in Microsoft terminology it is called namespace, I come from java world).

Anyway if you don't use predicates, you can create a value object with the searching keywords (like a DTO), and it would live as well in the same module than the aggregate.

Hope this explanation helps.