# How to search for the number of times that keywords will appear in several text between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and the they have the following columns.

```
articles: id (PK), article (longtext), date (date)

keywords: id (PK), keyword (varchar)
```

For the moment I can only do that, search for a hard keyword and display the text where the word appears the most times :

```
SELECT * , MATCH (article) AGAINST ("keyword*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM `articles` 
WHERE MATCH (article) AGAINST ("keyword*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 10
```

How can I search for the number of times each keyword (Table : keywords) appears in each text (Table : articles) ?

I have try that (I do not know if it's possible?) but I get "Invalid argument at AGAINST":

```
SELECT keyword
FROM keywords
CROSS JOIN articles
WHERE MATCH (keywords.keyword)
        AGAINST (articles.article IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

---

**EDIT FOR Gordon Linoff :**

```
Table : Keywords

Id     Keyword

1      first     
2      second   
3      text
4      keyword
```

-

```
Table : Articles

Id     Article

1      the first text     
2      the second text   
3      text text text
```

Desired results :

```
Keyword     score

text        5
first       1
second      1
keyword     0
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's good :)

Comment: . . Don't store lists in delimited strings.  That is the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing keywords in delimited strings is just the wrong way to store them.  You should have a junction/associate table with one row per keyword in each article.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad data models.  If this is your data model, you should spend your effort *fixing* it rather than *using* it.

But, you can do this, with some string manipulations:

```
select kw.motcle,
       sum( (length(d.articles) -
             length(replace(d.articles, mc.motcle, '')
            ) / length(d.articles)
          ) as cnt
from test_motcle mc left join
     articles a
     on fin_in_set(mc.motcle, replace(d.articles, ' ', ',') > 0
group by mc.motcle
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: Okay so you advise me to make the @Yaakov Ellis solution for store my keywords, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging ?

Comment: @SkroS2 . . . New questions should be asked as *questions* not *comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
select kw.motcle, count(d.articles)
from test_motcle kw left join
     articles d
     on concat(' ', d.articles, ' ') like concat('% ', kw.motcle, ' %')
group by kw.motcle
ORDER BY count(d.articles) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

:)