# How to link only the content of one row of a table to a column of another table?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a table named `videos`. It has three columns `id`, `title`, `tags`. Since the tags of a video may be many, I create another table named `videos_tags`, which has `id`, `life`, `school` and `activity` as its columns, and the `id` of `videos_tags` should match the `id` of `videos`.

The table `videos_tags` is like this:

```
  id    life    school    activity
  123    0        1          0
```

My objective is to be able to fetch corresponding tags of a video. What I did was I gave the `tag` column in the table `videos` a number which should be the `id` of the table `videos_tags`, as follows

```
  id    title    tags
  1     avideo    123
```

So, I would get the tag reference id by the following:

```
SELECT tags FROM videos WHERE id=1
```

And then I would run the `SELECT` statement again to fetch the corresponding tags of the video by the `id` of the tag fetched in the table `videos`, as follows

```
SELECT * FROM videos_tags WHERE id=123
```

There we go, we have the tags we need.

My question is: **is there a way to fetch tags by some kind of relational tables which, for example, use foreign keys, and will it simplify the query code further?**

My concern is the approach I used had a weak connection between the `tags` in the table `videos` and the `id` of the table `videos_tags`, since when you modify, say, the `id` of the `video_tags`, the `tags` in `videos` will not change, which may cause a really huge problem to the program at some point.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just tried it out and it did simplify a bit the code. But the concern still stands. I know that if making sure to `INSERT` the same value `INTO` `tags` in `videos` and `id` in `videos_tags`, we could greatly reduce the concern, but either approach doesn't address the problem that a change in one table won't affect the other table, where information may not match up in subsequent calls.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't see Gordon's comment when I posted mine.. For data integrity - search for "*foreign key*" and `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. For tag organization - see: [recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel that helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended SQL database design for tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging)

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to understand that:

- a Tag exists independent (of any Video that tags it)
- the relation for your Video::Tag is multiple, 1-to-n

  - you have set it up for 3, and it is fixed
  - where there are less than three Tags, you have NULLs
  - you cannot add a Tag in future ... if you do, it will be heartache, structural change, and code changes.

As a result of that, you have made things far more complex than they really are.  As well as fixing the table in concrete (hard to change in the future), and when it does, everything, all code, has to change.

> Possible duplicate of [Recommended SQL database design for tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging)

Yes.  But the Accepted solution there is not Relational, and therefore it has none of the Integrity; Power; or Speed, of Relational systems.  I will take you step-by-step from what you appear to understanod, to the best design.

### 1960's Record Filing System • Degenerate & Deranged

If you follow the "literature" or "textbooks" or "articles" that are purported to be "relational", you will come up with this:

[image: Deranged]

- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/), the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading.

### 1960's Record Filing System • Degenerate

If you elevate it *in the direction of* Codd's *Relational Model*, while remaining in the physical `Record Id` mindset, which is what Yaakov Ellis means by "proper indices, etc" (I am giving you much more than that) ... we get this:

[image: Degenerate]

- This prevents duplicate rows (fundamental requirement in the *RM*)
- It removes duplicate declarations, and eliminates circular references and the horrendous consequences that that particular madness ensures
- This still has one additional `Record Id` and one additional index, per table, that is required to support the physical-isation of data using primitive records, which is totally unnecessary (these crutches are essential for intellectual cripples such as Date & Darwen and their followers).
- Of course, you can make up anything between the **Deranged** and the **Degenerate**, it still remains in the 1960's Record Filing System category, devoid of Relational capability.

### Relational Database

Since you have tagged `SQL & Relational Database`, you may wish to tune out the black noise and follow Codd's *Relational Model*.  If you do, you will get this:

[image: Relational]

- Human users will not use a `VideoId` number.  The `FullTitle` is awfully long and cumbersome.  They will use a short title, which is missing in the primitive system
- Neither will they use `TagId`.  They want the Tag
- I have given the more relevant Predicates, so that you can check them for yourself
- Adding or deleting a Tag is effortless
- no structural changes in the future, and therefore no code changes.

### SQL

> My concern is the approach I used had a weak connection between the tags in the table videos and the id of the table videos_tags, since when you modify, say, the id of the video_tags, the tags in videos will not change, which may cause a really huge problem to the program at some point.

- Yes, all those concerns have vaporised.
- Removal of the `Id` fields and Normalising the Tags properly, eliminates that problem
- And the horrible two-step method is eliminated.
- One of the hallmarks of a genuine Relational database is that any report can be produced from a single `SELECT` command.

> My question is: is there a way to fetch tags by some kind of relational tables which, for example, use foreign keys, and will it simplify the query code further?

Another hallmark is simple, straight-forward SQL code.  Given a Video title (the short one that people will naturally use), find the videos that have any of its Tags:

```
SELECT   VT.VideoTitle
    FROM VideoTitle VT      -- outer query
    WHERE Tag IN
    (SELECT VT_IN.Tag
        FROM VideoTag VT_IN -- inner subquery
        WHERE VT_IN.VideoTitle = @VideoTitle
        )
```

If you want to include the full title in the report:

```
SELECT   VT.VideoTitle,
         V.FullTitle
    FROM VideoTitle VT      -- outer query
    JOIN Video V
         ON VT.VideoTitle = V.VideoTitle
    WHERE Tag IN
    (SELECT VT_IN.Tag
        FROM VideoTag VT_IN -- inner subquery
        WHERE VT_IN.VideoTitle = @VideoTitle
        )
```