# How to search in sql if any string char of a string is contained in another string?

Tags: sql, db2

I am developing some complex sql conversion queries where I have to search a column with concatenated chars (e.g. 'LKA') for another string with concatenated chars in any order (e.g. 'AL').

I already tried using the `LIKE` keyword like this:

`SELECT UMCOD FROM x WHERE UMCOD LIKE y`
Where `UMCOD` is for example `LKA` and y `AL`. This clearly cannot work because I did not use wildcards.

For example I have the following sql tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `searchable_chars` ( `charstring` CHAR(9) NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE `searchme` ( `tosearch` CHAR(9) NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO `searchable_chars` (`charstring`) VALUES ('LKA');
INSERT INTO `searchme` (`tosearch`) VALUES ('AL'), ('L'), ('U'), ('KU'), ('A');
```

The query (like the one below not working):

```sql
SELECT x.charString, y.toSearch FROM `searchable_chars` AS x LEFT JOIN `searchme` AS y ON x.charstring LIKE y.toSearch
```

should return the following table

```
+------------+----------+
| charString | toSearch |
+------------+----------+
| LKA        | AL       |
| LKA        | L        |
| LKA        | KU       |
| LKA        | A        |
+------------+----------+
```

I hope you know what I mean. I know how to solve it using js or any other language, but I want to solve it using pure SQL.

Comment: You can use a statement with `LIKE` for each individual character in the `charString` and `UNION` the results, but what you are asking cannot be done in a single `SELECT` query. You're going to have to mix together more complicated logic to achieve what you want.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner Yeah, I already thought that it wouldn't be possible. I thought that maybe there is some function I don't know which converts the string into a array or something.

Comment: This is reminiscent of querying a [tag database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20856/812837).  Not only will any query used here be _extremely_ expensive, relatively (because indices will **not** be helpful - you have to text-search the entire table), you're going to have all the fun of dealing with a delimited column as well.  What do these strings represent?

Comment: Yeah, it would but the query would only run once per night.
The strings represent allocations to a special "group" which is sadly not defined in any table, just written here.
So you can allocate table x multiple times with table y and reverse.

Bad DB design of the existing system in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

try below query..

```
SELECT x.charString, y.toSearch FROM `searchable_chars` AS x LEFT JOIN `searchme` AS y ON x.charstring LIKE '%'+ y.toSearch +'%'
```

Comment: This query does not return `AL` or `KU`. In addition, I had to replace `'%'+ y.toSearch +'%'` with `CONCAT(CONCAT('%', y.tosearch),'%')`

Comment: try in concat function

Answer (score 0):

I have not used DB2, but according to documentation there is a `REGEXP_LIKE` predicate which might possibly be used to do what you want:

```
SELECT x.charString, y.toSearch FROM `searchable_chars` AS x 
LEFT JOIN `searchme` AS y ON REGEXP_LIKE(x.charstring , '[' + y.toSearch + ']')
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm

As I have no DB2 instance, I have not tried this...

Comment: Yeah, I already found that, but sadly my sql server does not support `REGEXP_LIKE`. Maybe it's too old.

Comment: Seems you could use XQuery (which has regexp support) instead for this beahvior: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80498/21515

Comment: Tried that yesterday but got syntax errors, will try that again today.

Comment: Good luck! There also seems to be alternative syntax for `REGEXP_LIKE` where you need to compare the result to a `BIT` e.g. `REGEXP_LIKE(<x>, <y>) = 1` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_regexplike.html

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help, will try that later and give a feedback here.