# MySQL - Merging two queries that have different conditions and limits

Tags: mysql

I'm implementing a Tag System for my website, using PHP + MySQL.

In my database, I have three tables:

**Posts**

| Id | Title | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |

Primary Key: Id

**Tags**

| Id | Tag | Slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First Tag | first-tag |

Primary Key: Id | Key: Slug

**TagsMap**

| Id | Tag |
| --- | --- |

Primary Key: both

(Id = post's Id in Posts; Tag = Tag's Id in Tags)

Given, for instance, the url *www. ... .net/tag/first-tag*, I need to show:

- the tag's name (in this case: "First Tag");
- the last 30 published posts having that tag.

In order to achieve this, I'm using two different queries:

firstly

```
SELECT Tag FROM Tags WHERE Slug = ? LIMIT 1
```

then

```
SELECT p.Title FROM Posts p, Tags t, TagsMap tm
WHERE p.Id = tm.Id
AND p.DateTime <= NOW()
AND t.Id = tm.Tag
AND t.Slug = ?
ORDER BY p.Id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

But I don't think it's a good solution in terms of performance (please, correct me if I'm wrong).

So, my question is: **how (if possible) to merge those two queries into just one?**

Thanks in advance for Your suggestions.

Comment: You should not use comma based joins. Use `join` and define relationships with `on`s. You have `t.Slug = ?` already so why do you need the first query? A SQL fiddle with larger data set might help question.

Comment: @user3783243 I need the first query to get the Tag name in order to show it as the page's title. But I'm the first to say it's not a good solution.

Comment: Why don't you have a unique primary key on *each* of your tables?

Comment: @Martin I've edited my question (see tables).

Comment: `t.name` should have the tag it in. Include that in your second select and the first shouldnt be needed

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you for your suggestion. The reason for the first SELECT lies essentially in LIMIT 1, which should speed up the search for the Tag. That's why my first approach was doing two different queries.

Comment: You join the `tags` table anyway though so you already have the full name there.

Comment: Please don't include links to ads.

Comment: @Rick James I didn't know it was a real website. I've edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the "Tags" table should have columns "tag" and "post_id"?  And may "slug" is a red herring?  Or maybe slug == post_id ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you have shown above is not a optimal solution as first it creates a `cartesian product` of all the tables and then filters out the data based on the conditions. If these tables become heavier in future, then your query will start slowing down (`SLOW QUERIES`).

Please use joins over this approach. ex. `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` etc.

**Try this SQL:**

```sql
SELECT t.*, p.* FROM Tags t 
INNER JOIN TagsMap tm ON (tm.Tag = t.Id )
INNER JOIN Posts p ON (p.Id = tm.Id AND p.DateTime <= NOW())
WHERE t.slug LIKE 'First Tag'
ORDER BY p.Id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Using this query, I get twice the Tag ('First Tag') for every single post. I need to get the Tag just once (for the title of the page), and not for every single post showed.

Comment: @Salvino: MySQL's query optimizer does not do a cartesian product for old-style SQL-89 join syntax. It does a nested-loop join just like when you use INNER JOIN. It's a good idea to use the more modern syntax, but in fact they optimize the same.

Comment: @BillKarwin I think we got you wrong. You said you get the tag twice, but the slug is unique across all the tags right? or is it not?

Comment: Every single Tag has its own, unique Slug ("First Tag" => "first-tag", "Second Tag" => "second-tag", and so on).

Comment: Okay, great. So you are saying you are getting `First tag` twice for each post right? Could you just make one check in the db? See if there are two identical mapping entries in the `TagsMap` table for `First tag`?

Comment: Checked: there aren't.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner [this](https://i.imgur.com/XgRW3Mn.png) is the max, that can be achieved at SQL level. You will have to do the filtration at code level using associative arrays.

Comment: simply `GROUP BY Tags.tag` on your SQL to remove duplicate tags.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use your query.

Comment: Just a question: is there a specific reason you prefer using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: You’ll use `INNER JOIN` when you want to return only records having pair on both sides, and you’ll use `LEFT JOIN` when you need all records from the “left” table, no matter if they have pair in the “right” table or not. Check [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-inner-join-vs-left-join/) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have structured your tables in a manner where you can utilize foreign keys and match them with their counterparts, then you can make use of `JOIN`'s in your query.

```
SELECT
    Tags.Tag,
    Posts.title
FROM
    Tags
LEFT JOIN
    TagsMap ON Tags.id = TagsMap.tag
LEFT JOIN
    Posts ON TagsMap.id = Posts.id AND
    Posts.DateTime <= NOW()
WHERE
    Posts.id = TagsMap.id AND
    Tags.Slug = ?
ORDER BY
    Posts.id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

The idea is that the query is optimized, but you will need to filter your result set programmatically in the view, in order to display the `Tag` only once.

Comment: Using this query (I've added the missing WHERE Clause), I get the Tag ('First Tag') for every single post. I need to get the Tag just once (for the title of the page), and not for every single post showed.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner try the updated version, utilizing a subquery.

Comment: The new query returns wrong results: posts not having desired tag.

Comment: In terms of SQL, there isn't a way to only return a result once for a field and continue with the rest. You will always get all associations, I.e. the tag will always be a part of the result. It's up to you to filter it (either on the back or front) if you want it to be displayed only once. Because in your result set, each title is associated with a tag and slug.

Answer (score 0):

If there is at most one "slug" per "post", include `slug` as a column in `Posts`.

If there can be any number of "tags" per "post", then have a table

```
CREATE Tags (
    post_id ... NOT NULL, 
    tag VARCHAR(..)... NOT NULL,
    post_dt DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(post_id),
    INDEX(tag, dt)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And you may want to use `LEFT JOIN Tags` and `GROUP_CONCAT(tag)`.

I don't know what you mean by "first" in "first_tag".  Maybe you should get rid of "first"?

The last 30 posts for a given tag:

```
SELECT p.*,
       ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag) FROM Tags ) AS tags
    FROM ( SELECT post_id  FROM tags  WHERE tag = ?
              ORDER BY post_dt DESC  LIMIT 30 ) AS x
    JOIN posts AS p ON p.id = x.post_id
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you suggest using only two tables (Posts and Tags), while I have chosen the so-called "Toxi Solution" (3 tables). Right? The reason there is a Slug for each Tag is because the latter could be made up of several words and have accented letters (e.g. black cafè -> black-cafe). "first-tag" is just an example of the Slug format.

Comment: P.S. Every post may have one or more tags associated to it.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner - (`LEFT` allows for zero tags.)  For accents, a suitable "collation" will automatically see cafè == cafe == Cafe == CAFE.  The hyphen is a harder thing to handle in a generalized search.

Comment: WordPress (just to give an example) uses just that format for tags slugs (website/tag/slug-of-the-tag). But you didn't answer me: do you propose a solution based on two tables (Posts and Tags)? If so, where do I get the list of available tags from?

Comment: In news feeds "slug" is a cryptic string of letters that uniquely identifies a news story -- quite different from a "tag" which is not unique.  I am not familiar with WP's meaning; it sounds like it is a sanitized version that avoids accents, caps, punctuation, etc.  It is easy to programmatically turn a "tag" into such a "slug", but not the other way.

Comment: Given that a post can have many tags, and the same tag can be associated with many posts, my 2-table is best.  (Again, I am ignoring WP.)  The wp_postmeta is a terrible way to implement tags; if that is how it is implemented, you have my condolences.

Comment: 3-tables or 2-tables, that is the question... (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging). Thank you for your condolences.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner - Yaakov's 3-table approach is the standard.  I find that my 2-table approach to be simpler, smaller, faster.  In several implementations, I go for 2-tables.  You are welcome to use either; I have stated my _opinion_.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner - My 2-table implementation seems to be "Scuttle".  If you get performance problems on ands/ors/etc, open a new question.  That 16-year-old link does not provide optimal SQL for current MySQL.

Comment: Another implementation is 1-table, where a column called `tags` contains a commalist of the tags.  `FIND_IN_SET()` comes in handy.  (That says you cannot use `,` in any tag.)  I recently analyzed 1-table vs 2-table and decided that 2 was "better".