# Select records that match several tags

Tags: sql, database-design, tags

I implemented a standard tagging system on SQLite [with two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging).

Table `annotation`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS annotation (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        comment TEXT
)
```

Table `label`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS label (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        annot_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES annotation(id),
        tag TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

I can easily find the annotations that match tags 'tag1' OR 'tag2' :

```
SELECT * FROM annotation
        JOIN label ON label.annot_id = annotation.id
        WHERE label.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2') GROUP BY annotation.id
```

1. But how do I select the annotations that match tags 'tag1' AND
   'tag2'?
2. How do I select the annotations that match tags 'tag1'
   AND 'tag2' but NOT 'tag3'?

Should I use INTERSECT? Is it efficient or is there a better way to express these?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with [INTERSECT](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-intersect/) for question 1 and [EXCEPT](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-except/) for question 2. After many years of experience with SQL I find it best to go with whatever the platform offers in cases where it directly addresses what you want to do.

The only exception would be if you had a really good reason not to. In this case, intersect and except are not ansi standard, so you are stuck with sqlite for as long as you use them.

If you want to go old school and use ONLY straight up SQL it is possible using subqueries, one for tag A, one for tag B, and one for tag C. Using an outer join with an "is null" condition is a common idiom to perform the exclusion.
Here is an sqlite example:

```
create table annotation (id integer, comment varchar);
create table label (id integer, annot_id integer, tag varchar);
insert into annotation values (1,'annot 1'),(2,'annot 2');
insert into label values (1,1,'tag1'),(2,1,'tag2'),(3,1,'tag2');
insert into label values (1,2,'tag1'),(2,2,'tag2'),(3,2,'tag3');

select distinct x.id,x.comment from annotation x
join label a on a.annot_id=x.id and a.tag='tag1'
join label b on b.annot_id=x.id and b.tag='tag2'
left join label c on c.annot_id=x.id and c.tag='tag3'
where 
  c.id is null;
```

This is set up so that both annotation 1 and 2 have tag1 and tag2 but label 2 has tag3 so should be excluded the output is only annotation 1:

| id | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | annot 1 |