# How do I efficiently filter images by tags

Tags: c#, database

I am creating an application that is used to view images in C# using WPF. The source of said images is a local folder and every image is intended to have a set of tags. Using these tags you are supposed to be able to filter the images, say filtering for the tag 'cat' will only show images that are tagged with 'cat' and hide everything else. One image can have between 5 and 30 tags and the local folder will contain up to about 40.000 images.

My main question is how would I go about **efficiently storing and querying** these images based on their tags?
Based on what I have gathered from doing a bit of browsing I assume I need some kind of database to store my tags in but I have minimal experience with databases, but I have not managed to find anything that looks like it is both intended to be contained locally and interfaces greatly with C#.

Any suggestions on what I should look into are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended SQL database design for tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/recommended-sql-database-design-for-tags-or-tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will likely be something like SQLite:

https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

There is an official nuget package for C# that you can also use:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/

You'll want a table for the images, a table for tags, and a table for image-tags. This relationship is a multivalued dependency, more information can be found here:

https://www.javatpoint.com/dbms-multivalued-dependency

Here's how that is structured:
https://dbdiagram.io/d/64bfe9ad02bd1c4a5eac934c
[image: Multivalued dependency diagram]

To get all of the tags for an image, you can use the following:

```
SELECT name
FROM Tags
WHERE IMAGES_Tags.image_id = 'your image id'
INNER JOIN Images_Tags ON
Images_Tags.tag_id = Tags.id
```

Replace 'your image id' with the image id you are checking.

Comment: I do not quite understand the difference between the tags and image-tags in the example you have given. Could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: See edit, hope that helps!