# PROC SQL like operator

Tags: sql, sas

I was just wondering if there is a way to implement a like with a % sign for a variable. I basically want region to contain market and any other characters for there to be a match. An example is if REGION = ALBANY-SXSX-TVTV and market=ALBANY,I want there to be a match between region and market.

```
select a.*, b.Code,b.HHLDS
from Master1 as a left join map as b
on a.region like "b.market%"; /*not sure about this*/
```

Comment: @BellevueBob I think that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484/use-a-like-clause-in-part-of-an-inner-join) is what you are looking for in a pure SQL.

Comment: @agstudy Perfect!  Got a solution now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comment from agstudy, here is a solution very similar to the one ps2goat gave, with some simple sample data:

```
data Master1;
   length region $30;
   input region;
   datalines;
ALBANY-SXSX-TVTV
ALBANY2-SXSX-TVTV
SEATTLE-SXSX-TVTV
NEWYORK-SXSX-TVTV
run;

data map;
   length market $10 code $1;
   input market code;
   datalines;
ALBANY A
SEATTLE B
run;

proc sql noprint;
   create table a as
   select a.*, b.Code
   from Master1 a 
   left join map b
   on a.region like '%' || trim(b.market) || '%';
quit;
```

Please note that this used the concatenation operator (**||**) instead of the CAT function.  However, CAT doesn't work; to use ps2goat's solution, you must use the CATS function to remove extraneous blanks.  So it cab also be written as

```
   on a.region like CATS('%',b.market),'%');
```

Also note the use of single quotes; never use double quotes when making a character constant.  Text inside double-quotes is scanned by the Macro Processor for symbol substitution (and the percent symbol is a trigger).

Comment: +1! thanks for this reproducible solution! I would just add the market  variable in the final output `select a.*, b.Code,b.market` to make the solution clearer clearer.

Answer (score 1):

just use concatenation:

```
select a.*, b.Code,b.HHLDS
from Master1 as a left join map as b
on a.region like CAT("%",b.market,"%");
```

updated to use SAS concatenating function, and double quotes for string values.

Comment: Are you sure this will work. I tried this and got an error. Keep in mind that I am using SAS.

Comment: Did you try using single quotes instead? SAS usually attempts to resolve % signs inside double quotes.