# Join on number is contained in string

Tags: sql, oracle

In my oracle database i have 2 tables and i have to join them where in TABLE A i have column ID which is number, and TABLE B where i have column SCIDS which is varchar2. Here is some example:

```
TABLEA.ID | TABLEB.SCIDS
162       | 162,163
162       | 555,162,33
161       | 161
```

Some sql i tried

```
select A.ID
from TABLEA A
    left JOIN TABLEB B 
where "," || S.ID in "," || B.SCIDS
```

This does not work it return only the records that are not "array" in SCIDS e.g 3rd record 161.

How to return all ?

Comment: this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276344/like-operator-in-inner-join-in-sql

Comment: Poor table design. Never, ever store data as comma separated items - it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585979/sql-parse-comma-delimited-string-and-use-as-join

Comment: @KaushikNayak i get same result as my sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, though not completely efficient one

```
with dist_tablea
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT ID
           FROM TABLEA)

SELECT a.ID, B.SCIDS
  FROM dist_tablea a LEFT JOIN TABLEB b ON REGEXP_LIKE (b.SCIDS, '(^|,)'||a.id||'(,|$)')
```

**Output**:

```
    ID  SCIDS
-------  -------
    161 161
    162 162,163
    162 555,162,33
```

Comment: This worked thank you.

Comment: This does not work - it will match `ID = 16` and `SCIDS = 161,162` since it is doing sub-string matches and `16` is a sub-string of `161`. Also, using `REGEXP_LIKE` is much less efficient than just using `LIKE` (and adding in regular expressions adds no benefit here).

Comment: @MT0 ah you are right

Comment: @MT0 : Thanks! . Modified the pattern now.

Comment: @MasterYi : Check Now..

Comment: @KaushikNayak it works

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate commas before and after both fields and then use the `LIKE` operator:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2007/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA( ID ) AS
  SELECT 161 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 162 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLEB( SCIDS ) AS
  SELECT '162,163' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '555,162,33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '161' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLEA A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B
       ON ( ',' || B.SCIDS || ',' LIKE '%,' || A.ID || ',%' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2007/2/0)**:

```
|  ID |      SCIDS |
|-----|------------|
| 161 |        161 |
| 162 |    162,163 |
| 162 | 555,162,33 |
```

Also:

- When you use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` you need to specify the join condition in the `ON` clause.
- String literals are surrounded by `'` single quotes. Double quotes are used (primarily) to enforce case-sensitivity on object identifiers (i.e. column names).

Comment: This is also accepted answer